# Free distributed source control with visual studio integration?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, dvcs

I'm looking to move to distributed source control since I use multiple computers and often work offline. What if any distributed source control systems integrate with visual studio and how good is the integration?

Comment: do you really need full integration? would popping up a cmd window be so much trouble?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [Git](http://git-scm.com/)? You can host open source projects on [github](http://github.com/) for free.

For integration please refer to [Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) which indicates it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about integration with VS but I have used the excellent Tortoise Windows Explorer plugins. We use Tortoise-CVS and SVN all the time and they are fast and reliable.

They do a Tortoise-Hg plugin for Mercurial as well.

Comment: I too use TortoiseSVN, TortoiseCVS, and TortoiseHG and they work great.

Answer (score 2):

It may sound funny, but I rarely use my VS integration even though I have one.

Tortoises and command line work great, and Bzr and Hg have workable tortoises.

Answer (score 1):

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) does the job nicely for me and my team.

Answer (score 1):

Jared,

If you need distributed and VStudio integration, then you're talking about [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com)

The whole GUI is integrated with VStudio 2005 and higher, and SCC integration is available starting with VStudio 6.

It directly supports renaming and moving files from VStudio too.

Plastic SCM is free for students, for open source projects and most likely you can get some free licenses for personal projects too.

Answer (score 1):

There is [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) too, with TortoiseHG it is a Visual Studio Plaugin.

Comment: This is what I use. Very comparable to using Git and the freely available Git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I use subversion and tortoisesvn.  For integration with VS, I use VisualSVN which does cost money but it pretty cheap and works flawlessly.  There are free subversion source control provider packages for Visual Studio and I tried a few but VisualSVN worked so much better so I went with it.

Comment: SVN is NOT distributed source control and VisualSVN is NOT free.

Answer (score 0):

I like using [KilnHG](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) (which is an online wrapper around Mercurial) - it's free for small numbers of developers from what I can recall.