# git and ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, gitignore

Anyone know of good articles for setting up a new project with `git` and `ASP.NET MVC`?

Just wondering what to include and `ignore` and what to do about deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great post on [codebetter.com](http://codebetter.com) today. It is about OSS projects but I bet it is applicable to you as well because it is describing GIT.

The right part of the article is the link to [Kyle's blog](http://kylecordes.com) and especially [Getting Started with Git and GitHub on Windows](http://kylecordes.com/2008/04/30/git-windows-go/).

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip.

Posted the correct link below.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2009/03/12/hosting-your-oss-project-on-github.aspx

Answer (score 36):

### Gitignore

You asked about what to ignore -- here is my default .gitignore for ASP.NET MVC projects:

```
###################
# compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.pdb
*.dll.config
*.cache
*.suo
# Include dlls if they’re in the NuGet packages directory
!/packages/*/lib/*.dll
!/packages/*/lib/*/*.dll
# Include dlls if they're in the CommonReferences directory
!*CommonReferences/*.dll
####################
# VS Upgrade stuff #
####################
UpgradeLog.XML
_UpgradeReport_Files/
###############
# Directories #
###############
bin/
obj/
TestResults/
###################
# Web publish log #
###################
*.Publish.xml
#############
# Resharper #
#############
/_ReSharper.*
*.ReSharper.*
############
# Packages #
############
# it’s better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip
######################
# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sqlite
# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store?
ehthumbs.db
Icon?
Thumbs.db
```

### Setting up a new project

For help on setting up a new project, I would install [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) since you're most likely on Windows and check out [learn.github](http://learn.github.com/p/setup.html) to learn about getting started with git.
Of course, the master (Skeet) [suggests you do most everything from the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio/507369#507369) -- and I tend to agree with him.  Git is just easier that way IMHO.  If you'd like a handy git reference, check out the [git reference](http://gitref.org/).

### Deployments

As somebody else already mentioned -- check out [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) for deployments.  Those guys aim to be the 'Heroku of ASP.NET'.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. Two suggestions: first, you can add `*.user` after `*.suo`, as these are user-specific files (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/VisualStudio.gitignore). Second and **MOST IMPORTANTLY**, add `!/packages/*/lib/*/*.dll` after `!/packages/*/lib/*.dll`. Today I got bitten by this while trying to deploy to AppHarbor and had my build failing. After a while I finally figured some NuGet packages (like WebActivator and Ninject) use a folder structure under `lib` (i.e. `/packages/Ninject.2.2.1.4/lib/net40-Full/Ninject.dll`). Hope this helps others!

Comment: Another suggestion for Windows git development:  The new Windows Git client - http://windows.github.com/ It's geared for github, but you can use it with other local repositories (and even sync with hosted repos like bitbucket.org)

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi updated with your suggestion because I just got bit with this trying to use Entity Framework 5.x (which uses NuGet and stores in  a subdirectory format like you described)

Comment: Dan, now that NuGet supports [package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages), DLLs in subdirs are really no longer a problem; you just ignore **the whole folder** (i.e. `packages/`), and NuGet will download missing packages for you on build. The repo size drops dramatically without all those DLLs in there (mine got 47 MB lighter!)

Comment: If you're reading this and wondering "What the heck is package restore?" just check out this article: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using git and ASP MVC you should also check out AppHarbor http://appharbor.com/ for deployment and hosting. It integrates right into your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected link

http://codebetter.com/blogs/aaron.jensen/archive/2009/03/12/hosting-your-oss-project-on-github.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Mine is super simple:

```
*/packages/*
/packages/*
obj/
bin/
TestResults/
_ReSharper.*
*.csproj.user
*.resharper.user
*.resharper
*.suo
*.cache
*~
*.swp
*.resharper.user
*.rptproj.user
*.db
*.sdf
*.tmp
```

For the example of gitignore files check [github gitignore examples](https://github.com/github/gitignore) and one for visual studio [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/VisualStudio.gitignore)