# Can I use a GIT repository with SVN clients?

Tags: svn, git, tortoisesvn, git-svn, ankhsvn

Currently I'm using the following SVN clients: TortoiseSVN for Windows and AnkhSVN for Visual Studio 2005+. I heard that GIT has a great level of interoperability with SVN. Would my tools work with a GIT repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least, regarding Tortoise, you have a git-equivalent:

[**TortoiseGit**](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).

[image: Context Menu from tortoisegit.googlecode.com/git/doc/images/en/ContextMenuDirControl.png]

And [**gitExtension**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions) can help with Visual Studio, as mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 6):

Nope. Use the git client. Git is more complex than SVN and has a very different structure.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub.com has read/write support for SVN clients to their Git hosted repositories: https://github.com/blog/644-subversion-write-support

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout a git repository but you can't do most of other operations. You can setup tortoise git which provides same interface for Git although the commands are different.