# Git, can I use it instead of sourcesafe or subversion?

Tags: git, version-control

Can Git be used the same as sourcesafe, Can I implement it directly into visual studio to check-in/out code and see history?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This project apparently has an extension for Visual Studio](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).  I haven't tried it myself, though, I'm afraid.

There's a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) on here that you might want to look at...

Comment: Git extention for visual studio is okay, though wish they would integrate a better diff tool. Typically find that using TortoiseGit is a better option, though do all the compare via the File explorer.

Answer (score 1):

[gitextensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) provides one.  However, fundementally git operates in a very different way to sourcesafe, so you have to learn git.

If looking for something more robust than sourcesafe, but working much the same way, then consider [Sourcegear's Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) - it was designed to be a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using git for the past year or so. In my opinion the least friction comes from the command prompt/terminal.

If Visual Studio integration is important to you, and my other 2 choices were Subversion or SourceSafe, I'd certainly go with Subversion. [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) is an incredible product and well worth the price of admission.

As others have said git is a much different paradigm in the SCM world and should, in my opinion be explored without prior conceptions of how source control should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to what appears to be a [VS extension](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)