# should ignore pdsyncu and pdsync files which is part of visual studio project when i using git?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, git, version-control

this file is not included in formmer questions such as

[Files to ignore when using Visual Studio with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677113/files-to-ignore-when-using-visual-studio-with-git)

and

[.gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions)

but i dout whether these files should be ignored, anybody who is assured about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code is the only thing that should be committed. You don't want any artefacts committed to your repository. Ensure that your workflow does not carry any bad assumptions with it. Config files are another story. You want to track them, but you want them to be different (especially the connection strings) on different clones depending on their environment (eg. a CI server vs a developer's machine). Consider scripting or smudge/clean script (git attributes chapter in progit.org/book) for those cases.