# How to ignore .dll files from all directories

Tags: asp.net, .net, git, dll, gitignore

I have a project and it has a lot of directories containing .dll files. Now I want to ignore all files having .dll extension from all directory. I have .gitignore file in root directory.I tried many combinations but none seems to work.

Please help

Comment: Can we see your gitignore file to see what you have tried. Typically you just add the file type like this `*.dll`. But if you think you have a case sensitive issue (possible) you can try this: `*.[dD][lL][lL]`.

Comment: Try this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677113/files-to-ignore-when-using-visual-studio-with-git

Comment: I would agree with PAV, its better to identify the output folders that are created and exclude those since you may want to include some external dll's in your code - I have not used asp.net, but I assume it produces output in the same way as c#/c++ so you probably want to ignore "Debug" and "Release" and/or "Output" folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
*.dll
```

That will ignore all .dll files recursively, in all folders.

Answer (score 2):

**Ignoring files**
From time to time, there are files you don't want Git to check in to GitHub. There are a few ways to tell Git which files to ignore.

**Create a local `.gitignore`**

If you create a file in your repository named `.gitignore`, Git uses it to determine which files and directories to ignore, before you make a commit.

A .gitignore file should be committed into your repository, in order to share the ignore rules with any other users that clone the repository.

GitHub maintains an official list of recommended `.gitignore` files for many popular operating systems, environments, and languages in the `github/gitignore` public repository.

1. In Terminal, navigate to the location of your Git repository.
2. Enter `touch .gitignore` to create a `.gitignore` file.

The Octocat has a Gist containing some good rules to add to this file.

If you already have a file checked in, and you want to ignore it, Git will not ignore the file if you add a rule later. In those cases, you must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your terminal:

```
git rm --cached FILENAME
```

**Create a global `.gitignore`**

You can also create a global `.gitignore file`, which is a list of rules for ignoring files in every Git repository on your computer. For example, you might create the file at `~/.gitignore_globa`l and add some rules to it.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run the following command in your terminal:`git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`