# GitHub and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)

What's the most painless way for the Visual Studio developer to start using GitHub? Ideally the answer would involve a Visual Studio plugin, or some other integration app?

- What solutions are available today to view/update GitHub repositories?
- Can you rely or expect the same functionality as compared to other VS integrated source control plugins?
- What processes would you change, as a user, when approaching this use-case from the TFS or [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) scenarios?
- The current use case is in single-developer mode, but certainly this question is open to single dev and teams of any size.
- Any tools that are Visual Studio plug-ins would be considered 'top of the list'

Comment: Do you have questions not answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio ?

Comment: For Github specifically, the [GitHub extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.github.com/) might be the way to go

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) for general hints using git with Visual Studio.

The accepted answer was the [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions) project.

I'm not aware that github would require any specific extras beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) . It is not a visual studio plugin but it provides a GUI to the world of git (which can be irritating at first).