# Does github have a Visual Studio Addin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, github

We are about to start a project and preparing the development environment. I was searching the possibilities of using github along with Visual Studio 10.

so does github have a Visual Studio Addin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Git with Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)

Comment: especially since the release of "github for windows" i think 'using github with visualstudio' is legitimately a separate (though clearly related) question from 'using git with visualstudio'. I have no answers but am trying to have this question answered for myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) for general hints using git with Visual Studio.

The accepted answer was the [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions) project.

I'm not aware that github would require any specific extras beyond that.

Comment: I realise this is an old question but what about viewing github issues within VS?  similar to how netbeans integrates with bugzilla?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but for the benefit of anyone landing here, Github extensions for visual studio have just been announced:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/30/announcing-the-github-extension-for-visual-studio.aspx

So, as of that announcement, yes it does have an addin, but not for the version of visual studio that you are using.