# Backing up source code for a C# solution

Tags: c#, backup

I would like to make a backup copy of my Visual Studio 2013 MVC application which is only the source code. Such that I could open the solution on a new machine and have it compile after NuGet has downloaded the necessary packages and so on.

I realise that if the project was in TFS or similair I could go to the new machine and download it like that, however I am looking for a file copy solution.

Now while I could ZIP up the entire folder including binaries that seems like a sledge hammer approach. Having looked around there does not appear to be an easy way to do this. Has anyone got a solution or a utility I may have missed?

Comment: As you mentioned TFS, why would you _not_ use some sort of version control?  Git, subversion, or whichever you choose, but I would highly recommended using version control.  That will give you code security, as well as fulfill your need of copying to another machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple automatic backup system for Visual Studio projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439073/is-there-a-simple-automatic-backup-system-for-visual-studio-projects)

Comment: @dubstylee The reason for not using TFS in this case is that I need to hand code over to a third party and I don't want to give them access to our TFS server

Answer (score 1):

Use a version control system such as TFS, Subversion, PlasticSCM, git whatever. Seriously. Distributed VCSs like git or Mercurial will let you transport the whole repository easily.

If you insist on a pack&go approach, the ZIP tool of your choice will, most likely, support include / exclude rules based on file name patterns. For example, in Total Commander it's easy to exclude bin and obj folders.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this feature is called in English but there is something like **Clean solution** in Visual Studio. This will delete all the binaries and stuff that can be generated. I am not sure it will also delete NuGet downloads but you may give it a try. Afterwards, you can simply copy the project or solution folder.