# Can you interact with the index/staging area with TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I've been tasked with giving a presentation on Git to my colleagues, who are almost entirely Windows users who are used to using TortoiseCVS. I've been using Git for about a year, but I almost exclusively used the Unix command line interface.

So I've been trying to get familiar with the Windows GUI Git tools including TortoiseGit. But it seems to me that this is more than just GUI skin over the Git command line interface, and actually abstract some things completely away, specifically the index.

For instance, when I right click a new, unversioned file in the Windows Explorer, I can select "Add" from the TortoiseGit menu, and later commit this file, but this same menu item is missing from files which are already in Git, in which case I only see the option "submodule add".

Is there no way to interact with the index with TortoiseGit?

I'm looking for analogues to `git add`, `git diff --cached`, and `git reset HEAD`, specifically.

[Here's](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisegit-users/browse_thread/thread/c38550480df06da2/83a55c8957b4a74e?lnk=gst&q=index#83a55c8957b4a74e) a message to the Google group about this, but it was from last summer.

I'm using TortoiseGit version 1.6.5.0 and msysgit version 1.7.4.msysgit.0, if it matters. I installed these just a few days ago so they are probably reasonably up to date.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is: **no, you can't**.

For me, TortoiseGit is a tool that you can use to make the transition from – in your case – CVS to Git easier (like I wrote in my answer to [Does TortoiseGit actually make Git a lot easier to use like TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645732/does-tortoisegit-actually-make-git-a-lot-easier-to-use-like-tortoisesvn/5645910#5645910)). But once the transition is made and your colleagues get more familiar to Git, it's time to come up with the real tools.

And the most powerful tool to interact with Git is the command line. Period. The Git Gui and `gitk` are also usable, bring some convenience but lack explorer integration (at least in terms of overlays). But in times with multi headed development boxes: why don't keep the Git Gui open on one monitor (the one used for general management stuff) and work on the other?

I recently also did an introduction to Git in my team at work. We were used to TortoiseSVN, so I also showed them how to add files using Tortoise, how to commit and so on. But on every slide, I also noted what they have to type in the Git Bash to achieve the same result. That way, once they're a little more experienced, they can take out the introduction slides and peek at the commands they have to use.

Comment: Thanks, I was sort of afraid of that. Thanks for the tip on slides with both GUI stuff and command line invocations, that's a pretty good idea.

Comment: +1: Emphasizing the command line as the ultimate solution, rather than trying to work around it, is pretty important in my book. (And if you can handle programming, you can handle a CLI any day.)

Comment: I believe this answer is outdated.  There is certainly `git add` and `git reset` support, as well as diff against working copy, etc.

Comment: @ScottStafford: no, it isn't. One of the biggest problems with using TGIT is, that it doesn't adhere to the Git nomenclature but uses the vocabulary of SVN: `git add` adds changes to the index while the `add` option of TGIT means `add untracked files`. Also, they have no `reset` but a `revert` that would be `git checkout` in Git. Twisted your mind? Now you know why I'm against using TGIT (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645732/does-tortoisegit-actually-make-git-a-lot-easier-to-use-like-tortoisesvn/5645910#5645910)

Comment: @eckes: I stand corrected.  I never thought about the `add` difference -- since I always use TortoiseGit's commit GUI the distinction is less relevant.  For the record, true `reset` is available, though a bit buried: http://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html

Comment: Actually I found TortoiseGit to be somwehat confusing, it turned out better to use something more tuned for Git, e.g. SourceTree. While command line is the most powerfull, I work for a company where I have to switch between projects using Git, SVN, TFS, sometimes even multiple times per day, so it is easy to forget or mess up commands, therefore GUI is still useful - you just open a menu and see - aha, that's the command I want to execute now.

Answer (score 4):

To a limited extent, you can perform those actions within TortoiseGit.  For instance, there is a [reset](http://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reset.html) dialog.  They aren't prominently featured (I think) because using TortoiseGit means you have less need for the git index -- there are convenient and highly functional GUI methods for choosing and reviewing the things you intend to commit, so the index becomes less necessary.

That being said, TortoiseGit brings many useful things to the table for both the beginner and the advanced git user, though it is only a complement, not a replacement, to commandline.

As an additional transition, you might be interested in a batch file I use that blurs the line a little by allowing convenient invocation of those TortoiseGit GUI windows from the commandline: https://github.com/ses4j/tgit

Comment: Just out of interest: why would I need to use a crippled TortoiseGit form the command line???

Comment: And `Add` from the TGIT menu is a completely different thing than `git add` is.

Comment: @eckes: My preferred git workflow is to invoke most actions from commandline.  But rather than `git add`/`git commit -m` sequences (or the evil `git commit -am` which commits so many accidental files), I bring up TortoiseGit's commit GUI where I can review each changed file one by one with a double-click, make sure I added/removed whatever I intended, and edit the commit message all in one nice place.  Same for common simple actions of `log` and `diff` -- Maybe you can read unified diffs easily, but I prefer a list of files I can review one by one in a difftool.

Answer (score 4):

The truth is even worse than the answers so far have let on. I tried an experiment: `git add` some changes to the index, restore the working tree to match the current HEAD, and run a TortoiseGit commit.

It listed the changed file as one of the files eligible to be included in the commit, so it was aware something was changed, which gives the impression that at least it knows how to finish a commit that's already been staged by another tool. But when I chose it the commit actually used the working tree copy and **destroyed the uncommitted data** in the index and the commit ended up being a no-op on that file.

A dangerous tool, I think I'll be avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently hit the need of using `git add` to apply stash when there were changes to the same files and found that I can use it with a trick: have (create) a new file in the repo (.txt for example), open commit window that will show changed files along with the new one. Select all changed files and the new file. Right click on the new file and you will have `Add` command there. It will apply `git add` to all selected files. After that you can just `Revert` the new file.
All of that allowed me to apply stash over modified files.