# Does TortoiseGit allow selective staging, like git-gui?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-gui

This question:

[Can you interact with the index/staging area with TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063944/can-you-interact-with-the-index-staging-area-with-tortoisegit)

takes the position that TortoiseGit's main function is **not** to eliminate the need for the git command line, and in general, I agree.

However, git-gui has a feature I use a lot (maybe to compensate for bad workflow): the ability to selectively stage or unstage hunks or lines from the current patch in order to split a bunch of interspersed changes into coherent changesets in multiple commits.

The command-line alternative (for me, at any rate) is a bit clunky, so, ideally, I'd like to do the same selective committing in TortoiseGit.

So far I haven't found a way to do this, and I suspect, from the answer to the other question, that it isn't possible. Can anyone confirm this, please?

Comment: The only client on windows that has full support for selective staging in the GUI I've seen so far is [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). Thus said it has weak sides too, comparing to TortoiseGit or GitExtensions.

Comment: @Ivan Danilov: Thank you, SmartGit is love at first sight for day-to-day stuff. If you would like to make that into an answer, it'll compete very well...

Comment: I've answered plus somewhat expanded my very concise comment so it be counted as real answer :)

Comment: Git Gui also supports selective staging and commiting.

Comment: @ThomasS: Yes, it does.  If only it wouldn't get into a hung state so often on Windows, then I would be content to just use it; as it stands, I want something that works more reliably on Windows.  (I suspect this is some kind of MSYS[2] or MinGW (the library) glitch, because I don't remember this ever happening on Linux, but it happens to me all the time here on Windows.  Sometimes also with gitk, so it's probably a bug that TCL/wish.exe tickles, which is more likely to happen the more subprocesses a TCL program tries to read the output of.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only client on windows that has full support for selective staging in the GUI I've seen so far is [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html).

Thus said it has weak sides too, comparing to TortoiseGit or GitExtensions.

For me, main showstoppers in SmartGit are:

1. Inability to compare two revisions. You could only see diff between one and its parent (TortoiseGit can that).
2. Inability (well, it is somewhat strange, it is possible I didn't found the way) to limit log to some folder if I don't interested in everything (TortoiseGit can).
3. Integration with VisualStudio (somewhat subjective, but GitEx have it and it is very handy)

I remember that there was something else, but evaluating last version of SmartGit now I can't find it. Either it was fixed/added or I just forgot what thing I can't do that time.

In any case I'm using both GitEx and TortoiseGit for some things and for everything else console is the best tool.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and especially for introducing me to SmartGit -- I've fallen in love with it already. Clearly, the limitations you mention are valid, but as they don't form a significant part of my workflow, fine. (Others' mileages may vary, of course.)

Comment: Just for the record, my current version of SmartGit (2.1.7:2012-01-23) *does* allow you to look at the log for a given single folder (contents) or a single given file, as well as the whole tree.

Comment: Both TortoiseGit ans Git Extensions do, as of March 2012, support working with hunks. I think that the answer by Duncan Smart should be marked as answer for this question (no matter how good SmartGit is).

Comment: @Borek: Yeah, they have caught things up already, good update.

Comment: Shoutout to [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), as another Windows client which supports selective staging in a very intuitive format.  I use TortoiseGit for almost everything, and I launch Sourcetree when I want to use staging features.

Answer (score 55):

Yes it does now: see [issue 222](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/222) - it takes the same approach as TortoiseSVN where you:

> - right-click on file, choose "Restore after commit"
> - TSVN creates a copy of the file outside the working copy, the file is shown differently in > the commit dialog (maybe an overlay icon or a different color)
> - user can double-click the file to open it in TMerge or some other diff tool and undo all the changes that should not be committed, then save those changes
> - commit
> - after the commit is finished, the copy of the original file is moved back
>
> ([From TSVN Issue 68](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=68))

Comment: Duncan, thank you very much for that. I am now deeply in love with SmartGit, but to all the TSVN team, I say, don't be discouraged, keep up the great work; even though you have really spectacular competition, you're still amazing.

Comment: It's nice to see the TortoiseGit team creating a good, GUI-oriented way of doing this, rather than the sloppy GUI-over-a-console-app way most other git-gui's do things.  Now if they would only do the same for interactive rebase...

Comment: This isn't selective staging, though. It's a workaround. Selective staging means you can decide as you go _without creating a commit_ what you want and what you don't want. This doesn't. It is not correct to say that there is support for selective staging in TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 6):

From the look of [issue 222](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=222), the "`add -p`" feature isn't implemented yet.

> Could you add support for partially committing a file? (`git add -p`).
>   I understand the way TortoiseGit works is a bit different from the normal "`git index`", but still I would like to have support for this in some way.
>
> I'd love to commit only a few changes of a file.
>   For example, only commit a single line fix of the file, and leave the rest remaining in the working copy.

Answer (score 6):

SourceTree (https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) has a very intuitive GUI for selective staging. It is made to integrate with BitBucket (it is by the same company after all), but can easily work with any git repository.

I do still use TortoiseGit in parallel, especially because of some nice features like the revision graph.

Comment: In the four years since I asked this question, I've moved on considerably, passing from TortoiseGit to Syntevo SmartGit, and finally ended up at SourceTree, which I find brilliant for almost everything (including not only BB, but also GitHub). The 0.5% I can't do in SourceTree, I do on the command line.

Comment: sourcetree is great but it's a real shame they don't support linux

Answer (score 0):

There is the pull request which implement this feature from year 2020, hope it will be merged ASAP.

https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/pull/233

Comment: Also, a discussion is open at https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/2299, but pointing finally to the same PR.

Comment: It looks like it is merged. Waiting for a new release...

Comment: Yes, I am also waiting for a new release.

Comment: Maybe you can try one here: https://download.tortoisegit.org/tgit/previews/, but I'm not sure the latest preview version in 2021-07-25 contains such merged commits.