# Upgrade vs2013 to vs2015 for Git and Github source control (instead of using subversion AnkhSVN), Is this reasonable?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, github, version-control, visual-studio-2015

Now we using visual studio 2013 en subversion AnkhSVN for source control.

We would like change to using git and github for source control. We have developer increasing in development team.

And we would like to setup better structure for development, testing, staging, and live stage.

I have read that github fully integrated into visual studio 2015
( we are new with git & github)

Is this reasonable to Upgrade from vs2013 to vs2015 for Git and Github source control? ( according to price license)

Or we can stay with vs 2013 and using git en github just fine?

What more that make us should move to vs2015.

Any suggestion are highly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is a distributed revision control system, VisualStudio is a development environment.

There's no need to go for one in order to use the other.

You could of course stick to VS 2013 and use Git. Learn Git on the command line and you're able to use Git for anything, not only your VisualStudio projects. [Do version control outside your IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19358148/520162).

Maybe tomorrow you want to switch from VisualStudio to Eclipse or whatever. If you know how to use the command line, you just switch IDEs, not your version control front end.

Doing such you could unleash the full power of your version control and don't get limited by [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645732/does-tortoisegit-actually-make-git-a-lot-easier-to-use-like-tortoisesvn) that [hide features](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6063944/520162) from you.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment help me a lot. We have decide to stay with vs2013 and using Git, GitHub.  Now I have another question. Can we using Git in vs2013 without using Team Foundation Server (TFS)?  ( we work with several developer in project )