# Unable to create patch using TortoiseGit with working copy changes

Tags: tortoisegit

I am trying to create a patch using TortoiseGit, but I am not able to get the patch with working copy changes, means may there is no option for working copy changes in TortoiseGit.
     But I am able to create patch using committed changes. But I need the patch only for uncommitted changes. Please help on this.

Comment: Answer without Tortoise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory

`git diff` for unstaged changes. `git diff --cached` for staged changes.

Answer with TotoiseGIT: Not Possible (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063944/can-you-interact-with-the-index-staging-area-with-tortoisegit)

Comment: I think it is not duplicate. Because this question is TortoiseGit specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open Log Message dialog, Right click on `Working tree changes`, and Click `Show changes as unified diff`

   [image]
2. A TortoiseGitUDiff dialog is opened, Click the `File` menu, and Click the `Save as...`
   [image]
3. Give the patch a file name, Save, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can open the context menu on the Working Tree folder and select "Diff" or "Check for modifications" (you might have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while opening the context menu).

On the following dialog there is a "Save unified-diff"-button which provides the requested functionality.