# Is there a way that a Git server will support svn clients requests

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration

We are looking to migrate our svn respository to a git one.

We want to allow developers to continue using the svn command on the server and we do not want to educate our git users with git-svn client.

We saw that github has the ability to do so. 
do you know how we can achieve that behavior?

Comment: It'd be better if you asked the `svn` users to switch to `git`. Otherwise they won't have access to the nice features and eventually complain to you to switch back to svn.

Comment: eventually I will, but we need the support for both Use cases in transition plan

Comment: it baffles me why the SVN-Git debate is ongoing, I learnt SVN after Git.. and SVN is horrible

Comment: @Jaitsu - We all agree that git is better, the problem is that we want to make a transition that will not cause both users and scripts to adopt the git concept all together

Comment: @ekeren yeah sorry, that wasn't aimed at you... more the guys still using svn =]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using something like TortoiseSVN, it should be pretty straightforward to migrate to Git and continue to use TortoiseGit. Other than that, there are no SVN clients which can talk with Git.

Comment: +1 for TGit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645732/does-tortoisegit-actually-make-git-a-lot-easier-to-use-like-tortoisesvn/5645910#5645910). A perfect tool for hooking up TSVN users before telling them the really interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

There is project for serving git repository by svn protocol: https://github.com/bozaro/git-as-svn