# Is there lightweight git client for Windows?

Tags: git

Is there **lightweight** git client for Windows ?

I installed TortoiseGit which has dependency on msysgit. msysgit installation is ~1.6GB which totaly blows my mind. I thought only Oracle can bloat software like that :)

Thanks!

Comment: msysgit is 80 MB on my system. what version did you download?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Latest Git for Windows 1.7.10.x occupies 208M on my hard drive. The problem you're observing is that the software you're using to check the installed size does not honor NTFS hardlinks. For instance, if you would look at the `libexec` subdirectory using a recent version of [FAR](http://farmanager.com) in its "File links" mode (`Ctrl-9`), you'll see most binaries there have 107 links as they all really link to one executable file.

The other problem is that this is Windows, and some bits of Git are implemented as Unix shell scripts or in Perl and its two standard GUI front-ends (`git gui` and `gitk`) are implemented in Tcl/Tk; in a typical GNU/Linux (or *BSD or whatever) system you'd have these dependent runtimes installed system-wide but Git for Windows is condemned to carry them with itself as there's no sane packaging system which it could rely upon.

There are attempts to do clear-room reimplementations such as [`libgit2`](http://libgit2.github.com/) which could supposedly be used to implement a light-weight Git client, but all these attempts are seriously lacking in features compared with full-blown Git and will probably continue to do so because Git itself is evolving as well.

In short: I would just relax and proceed with Git for Windows. ;-)

Comment: :) Yep, I used FAR :) Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: A similar issue has recently been discussed in the msysgit bug tracker; the reporter stored his Git installation on a FAT32-formatted flash drive (so no support for hard links), and [he has been advised to simply delete all those `git-*.exe` files](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/58#issuecomment-7928140) as they're only maintained for backward compatibility (`git-add` vs `git add`).

Answer (score 3):

Try the [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) client. Even though it has some github-specific functions you do not *need* the repos to be in github.

If you dislike the metro style you won't like it though.

Comment: isn't this client only for github?

Comment: Nope, it also works fine with non-github repositories.

Answer (score 3):

Check out **GitExtensions**:

http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Comment: Thanks. 219MB is better than 1.6GB :)

Comment: It should be noted that Git Extensions either packages Git for Windows with itself (the so called "full version") or uses its existing installation, so using Git Extensions is not the way to combat disk space issues.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the 1.6GB for msysgit?

My `C:/Program Files/Git` directory containing msysgit is 'only' 222MB.

If you want to save space: drop Tortoise, use the git console, which ([in not only my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5645910/520162)) is the right way to unleash the full power of Git.