# How can I stage specific lines of file to git in NetBeans?

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I'm quite new to using NetBeans and today I faced a problem. I have used to stage only part of files to make better commits.

I have used vim and fugitive plug-in, where I can just move specific lines from unstaged to staged.

I can do a workaround by calling *git add -p*, but it would be nice to do it straight from NetBeans IDE.

Is there a mysterious way to do it simple by clicking somewhere and stage specific line(s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `git add -p` is not a workaround but **the way** to do it.

If you need it more comfortable, fire up `git gui` as [External Tool](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ExternalTools) out of NetBeans and use it to stage lines manually.

Regardless if you get that working somehow or not: this is **exactly** the reason why I advocate using **one tool for one task** and not trying to do everything in one.

In [Does netbeans ignore my git pre-commit hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362883/does-netbeans-ignore-my-git-pre-commit-hook), I discussed that the Git implementation of NetBeans is far from being complete. `git add -p` does not seem being contained in the [NetBeans Git integration plan](http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_plan).

NetBeans is using `jgit`. `jgit` does not provide means to stage parts of files, there's only the [`AddCommand`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#AddCommand_.28git-add.29) that provides `addFilepattern()`. So the answer to your question is **no**, it won't work.

Comment: As a workaround I meant that instead of able to do this in NetBeans I use git add -p.

But thanks for clearing this :)