# Can I use Visual Studio's built in git functionality against a

Tags: git

Can I use Visual Studio 2013s built in git features against a remote git repository that sits on a network drive if I do not have TFS ? I have read many articles, watched many videos and I am still unclear if I can pull it off.

Comment: Regardless whether it works or not, I would not recommend it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19358148/520162

Comment: Wow.  The down votes are getting out of hand on Stackoverflow.com.  I know there are tons of questions where folks do not try on their own and want you to do their work.  I have a legitimate question here that I researched for several hours before I reached out to the community for help.

Comment: I did not downvote, but why don't you simply try? What makes you unsure whether it works or not? What did the *many articles* and *many videos* tell you? What exactly should not work? The question makes me think *what's his actual problem* and this might other people bring to downvote the question or **flag** it with a reason set to **unclear what you're asking**...

Comment: The question is very straight forward and I did try.  There is no clear documentation as VS2013 is different than VS2012 when it comes to built in git features.  I do not want to keep trying if it is not possible.

Comment: and what were your results?

Comment: @eckes The results were that I could not view file system repositories within the IDE as remotes.  I will take some print screens this evening and post back showing you what I am seeing and not seeing that I expect to.  I get that the community wants to make sure people try and research on their own, it's just lately it seems  down voting has been abused. I can take it, but when I see a noob post a question that seems fair and they get down voted for what seems to be no reason, it's disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

IDEs are improving, but don't generally have great support for version control systems. A great solution is to install Git tools http://git-scm.com/download/win and use those tools to work with the distant repo. You can have a remote and a local repo. The local repo can be used with the IDE as far as commits are concerned. Any pushes pulls rebases or merges can be done using Git tools. As far as a network drive is concerned, it depends on the system. What is needed is a server for the repos. Github hosts for free but the free repos are public. Depending on what your needs are this might work or you might be better off paying for private repos. If you are a student there are some deals on storage for college students.

Comment: DasScooter I really appreciate your answer it is very helpful.