# Git Usage in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to learn to use Git in Visual Studio. It is very less friendly compared to the normal TFS or SVN. Also, there seem to be very less articles out there, which actually talk about using Git in TFS, step-by-step, though, there are a lot of youtube videos, which have a lot of advanced stuff. It will be great, if you can point me to some good video tutorials, which just talk about the basics of using Git in TFS for a developer on a day-to-day basis tasks. The concepts or terminologies in Git are really confusing. I can't go through 600 pages of books to just understand Git usage in Visual Studio. Hence, any good articles or video tutorials would be of great help.

Comment: Highly subjective comment: don't waste your time learning how to do git in a certain IDE: learn how to use git from any IDE http://stackoverflow.com/a/19358866/520162

Answer (score 0):

Just use Microsoft's official git plugins like [Visual Studio Tools for Git](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) depending upon your VS version.

The rest of your process depends upon which task management or tracker you are using like TFS, Jira or Redmine or whatever... There are plugins for those as well...

Comment: I am using TFS with Visual Studio. I need some good tutorials. Git is already part of Visual Studio Online. My customer has provided this already.