# Committing a project commits to the solution, why?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, commit

Whenever I commit a project in a solution, if I go to a Git Bash and do some `git log`, none of the commits are present in the project folder, however they're all present on the solution folder.

How is one supposed to do for having commits *per project* rather than for the solution ?

Should I just do everything by myself on the Git Bash rather than using the IDE ?

Comment: As far as I understand VS only support VCS per solution and not per project.

Comment: Alright, so the only option is to do it manually ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I just do everything by myself on the Git Bash rather than using the IDE ?

## YES

you should.

And there are (IMO) good reasons to do so:

- if you switch your dev environment (e.g. drop VS and choose Eclipse), **you still know your version control**
- you could use version control not only from within VS but also **for versioning things you don't edit with VS**
- **only the command line gives you the full functionality of Git**. I don't know any tool that doesn't hide important parts of Git.
- **YOU decide the repo structure, not the IDE** (I could hardly believe that VS creates repos per-project or per-solution. Are you really serious with that? YOU should be the one creating a repo!)

Don't get me wrong: VS provides by far the best *debugger* I've ever seen.
But when it comes to *version control*, I trust the console.

Nobody else.

---

Some questions related to the *Awesome-Command-Line-Vs-Crippled-Other-Tools* topic:

- [Is it a good practise to do version control from outside the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358148/is-it-a-good-practise-to-do-version-control-from-outside-the-ide)
- [Does netbeans ignore my git pre-commit hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362883/does-netbeans-ignore-my-git-pre-commit-hook)
- [Can you interact with the index/staging area with TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063944/can-you-interact-with-the-index-staging-area-with-tortoisegit)
- [Does TortoiseGit actually make Git a lot easier to use like TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645732/does-tortoisegit-actually-make-git-a-lot-easier-to-use-like-tortoisesvn)

Comment: I like to use [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) and [Git Source Control Provider](https://gitscc.codeplex.com/) with VS 2012. Occasionally i drop down to git command line. You do version control outside of the IDE, but the IDE still displays the file VCS status.