# Git status indicates no changes, but Idea shows more than 1000 files in default changelist

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I cloned a repo and imported gradle project by idea. But somehow right after Idea has completed import of project Idea's Changes widget showed me more than 1000 files in changelist.
After that git status showed me all those changes.

I stashed those changes and git status showed me no changes. But Idea still showes me those 1000 pseudo-changed files and revert files doesn't help.

Could anyone advise something?

Comment: this probably isn't what you want to hear but: **only trust the command line** (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21188318/520162 for a list of arguments why)

Answer (score 0):

I used SourceTree as GUI client and found changes in file permissions, so I found [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha)