# Git LFS refused to track my large files properly, until I did the following

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

## Problem

I had troubles trying to use [git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/), despite the many suggestions here on SO, on Git and GitHub's documentation, and on some Gists I'd run across.

My problem was as follows:

After performing the necessary steps:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "<file of interest>"
git commit
```

I would still not have any files being tracked.  If I performed

```
git lfs ls-files
```

it would be blank.  If I went ahead & performed the push, the transaction would fail, saying that the files are too large.  (As expected, but I was desperate.)

Comment: I forgot to ```git lfs install``` it solved the issue for me

Comment: @RavinSardal thanks!  I actually had not made that mistake, however I found that this error I was having is now obsolete.  I guess something within the LFS internals has been improved, such that having files tracked works more smoothly now.

Comment: To anyone who comes across this question, I do not think it is relevant anymore since Git LFS has improved significantly.  I am not sure if it is more helpful to delete it or keep it here, but notice that I wrote the question back in 2016.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To put files on an existing repo on lfs you can also do:

```
git lfs migrate import --include="*.mp3,*.pth"
```

(Replace `.mp3` and `.pth` with the file extension you wish to put on lfs)

Comment: Good to know a proper way of migrating has now been established.  :)

Comment: i think this works only if you are starting from a fresh repository and with the flarge files not already committed. in my case i had already committed the files and this did not work.

Comment: I did the old way, and then I use this command, and goes like a charm!

Answer (score 36):

## New Solution

The original solution is from 2016. Tech progresses...

Seems the best solution now is

```bash
git lfs migrate
```

Thanks to @iff_or for alerting me to this (see comments).

## Outdated Solution, don't use

I then discovered a few fixes, some of which seem to be bugs, some of which simply were not obvious to me.

1. It seems that in order to use `lfs` with an **existing repository**, a hack or third party tool such as [BFG's converter](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5) is needed.

   - I did not want to go that route, so I simply **initialized a new repository** locally, then did the challenge of hooking it back up to the real repo.
   - I created a new directory, then `git init`, etc.

     - In my case, the remote repository was GitHub.  So I did all those proper hookups like `git remote add origin git@github.com:<my_id>/<my_repo>.git`
2. Also, while [Git's Training Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLR1RNqJ1Mw) claims that you can simply **specify a folder**, such as `"my_folder/"`, I could not get this to work.  Therefore, I just cleverly used **filename extensions** to manage things.

   - For example, `git lfs track "my_folder/"` would not work for me, but `git lfs track "*.zip"` did work.
3. I had no luck getting LFS files to be identified correctly unless I had **first updated the `.gitattributes` file, and committed and pushed that new file to the remote server**.

   - `git lfs track "*.zip"`
   - `git add .gitattributes`
   - `git commit -m "Updated the attributes"`
   - `git push`
   - `git add my_large_file.zip`
   - `git lfs ls-files`

     - And here I would ensure that I saw `my_large_file.zip` being tracked.
   - `git commit -m "Now I am adding the large file"`
   - `git push`

---

It's possible that some of the things work, and I was simply doing them wrong.  However, following the witchcraft described above finally got LFS to work, so I thought I'd pass on these details for others, in case someone else had the same problem.

Comment: Hey Mike, I was having all the same problems. I was able to resolve my issues by upgrading to the latest version of git-lfs. Unfortunately, there is no clear documentation for this, so I just downloaded 1.1.2 and ran the shell script again. `git lfs track "directory"` works for me now.

Comment: Hi @MattBorn, thanks for the info!  I actually had *just* downloaded git-lfs, so I'm pretty sure that wasn't the problem.  Regardless, I was able to solve mine, and I wrote the solution above in case others have problems, and as my own future documentation.

Comment: Good overview. I also can't get the folder tracking to work. Any idea why that might be? I can't really rely on extensions for my case.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, sorry, I am not sure.  When I wrote this original answer, Git LFS was quite new, and I felt like many of these "small" issues would eventually sort themselves out.  If the folder tracking *still* isn't working, I'd recommend documenting the problem and submitting the bug to Git.  I suspect / hope that LFS is far enough along that they are now starting to address these bugs.

Comment: Git LFS with github remote tracking *does not* track the file until the gitattribute file is pushed to the LFS remote server. This is true to new track globs as well. Always verify with `git lfs ls-files` before git push.

Comment: Thanks, @shadowbq ! Truth is, git lfs has changed so much and improved so much since I wrote this post that I think the question and answer have both become irrelevant. I'm not sure if the best practice according to SO policy is to leave this question & answer or delete the whole thing.  But anyone stumbling upon it these days should probably ignore both the question and the answers.

Comment: mostly it worked, at the end it said ..     http://.../.../abc.git/info/lfs/objects/batch from HTTP 502

Comment: @MikeWilliamson People can likely find this elsewhere on SO (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65498452/2389827) or in the LFS docs, but it might be helpful to update your answer to recommend `git lfs migrate` rather than the third-party tool!

Answer (score 13):

To track all files and sub directories of `my_folder` via LFS, you can do:

```
git lfs track "my_folder/**"
```

It worked for me.

Doing the following is not working as of now to track whole `my_folder` directory:

```
git lfs track "my_folder/"
```

is not working

Comment: How does it work for  tracking large files on a specific directory? Like all `*.mp4` files in `my_folder/sub_folder` for example?

Comment: I am not sure but, isn't git lfs track "my_foldersub_folder/*.mp4" working?

Comment: Using double star after the slash worked. Otherwise it was not recognising the sub-directories and its files.

Comment: @ruelluna I think it's `git lfs track "my_folder/sub_folder/**/*.mp4"`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments by @Ravin Sardal, all I had to do to fix the issue was to run

```
git lfs install
```

in the base directory of the repository to setup large file support. After that

```
git lfs track "<file of interest>"
```

worked as expected and indeed `git lfs ls-files` listed the tracked files before the commit.

Comment: `git lfs install` works for me, if you already add files, you should reset and re-add it to see it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add and commit .gitattributes first
2. Check on the checkbox of Include Git LFS objects in repo settings/archives.
3. add and commit the large file

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905325/this-repository-is-over-its-data-quota-account-responsible-for-lfs-bandwidth-sh)