# Git not staging .mp4 files from subdirectory

Tags: git, gitlab, gitignore, git-stage

I have been facing this problem with git in which I am trying to upload `.mp4` files in a subdirectory of `wwwroot/` but whenever I am writing `git status`, they won't appear.

The new video files are located inside `wwwroot/Content/Videos/ZoomEspecialista/`
This problem has never occured before. I have uploaded maybe 10-15 new `.mp4` files.

Regardless of that, in my `.gitignore` file, I am not excluding the folder which contains these .mp4 files. I have checked multiple times to see if there is something, but I think the problem lies somewhere else. If anyone has any idea on how to tackle this issue, it would be superbly appreciating. Thanks!

[image]

The only thing I get from doing a git status is this despite of having uploaded my files to that subdirectory:

[image]

EDIT 2: Here is my .gitignore file:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
##
## Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

# User-specific files
*.rsuser
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/


# Visual Studio 2015/2017 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
bin/
obj/


# Visual Studio 2017 auto generated files
Generated\ Files/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# Benchmark Results
BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts/

# .NET Core
project.lock.json
project.fragment.lock.json
artifacts/

# StyleCop
StyleCopReport.xml

# Files built by Visual Studio
*_i.c
*_p.c
*_h.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.iobj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.ipdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*_wpftmp.csproj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db
*.VC.VC.opendb

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap

# Visual Studio Trace Files
*.e2e

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# AxoCover is a Code Coverage Tool
.axoCover/*
!.axoCover/settings.json

# Visual Studio code coverage results
*.coverage
*.coveragexml

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
# Note: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings,
# but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# Microsoft Azure Web App publish settings. Comment the next line if you want to
# checkin your Azure Web App publish settings, but sensitive information contained
# in these scripts will be unencrypted
PublishScripts/

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/[Pp]ackages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/[Pp]ackages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/[Pp]ackages/repositories.config
# NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignorable files
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets

# Microsoft Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Microsoft Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/

# Windows Store app package directories and files
AppPackages/
BundleArtifacts/
Package.StoreAssociation.xml
_pkginfo.txt
*.appx

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!?*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.jfm
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
orleans.codegen.cs

# Including strong name files can present a security risk
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2483#issue-259490424)
#*.snk

# Since there are multiple workflows, uncomment next line to ignore bower_components
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1529#issuecomment-104372622)
#bower_components/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm
ServiceFabricBackup/
*.rptproj.bak

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf
*.ndf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings
*.rptproj.rsuser
*- Backup*.rdl

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat
node_modules/

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio 6 auto-generated workspace file (contains which files were open etc.)
*.vbw

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe
paket-files/

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/

# JetBrains Rider
.idea/
*.sln.iml

# CodeRush personal settings
.cr/personal

# Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)
__pycache__/
*.pyc

# Cake - Uncomment if you are using it
# tools/**
# !tools/packages.config

# Tabs Studio
*.tss

# Telerik's JustMock configuration file
*.jmconfig

# BizTalk build output
*.btp.cs
*.btm.cs
*.odx.cs
*.xsd.cs

# OpenCover UI analysis results
OpenCover/

# Azure Stream Analytics local run output
ASALocalRun/

# MSBuild Binary and Structured Log
*.binlog

# NVidia Nsight GPU debugger configuration file
*.nvuser

# MFractors (Xamarin productivity tool) working folder
.mfractor/

# Local History for Visual Studio
.localhistory/

# BeatPulse healthcheck temp database
healthchecksdb
```

EDIT 3: Moreover, by delving a bit further, I found out that I have two hidden folders `.git`. One is located inside my repo and one is outside of it.

INSIDE REPO

[image]

OUTSIDE OF REPO

[image]

Comment: could you post the entire content of the .gitinore (and double-check you only have one of those in the repo)?

Comment: sure, I will do that right away.

Comment: So obj is ignored but still pops up. Strange. Where is gitignore located? In wwwroot?

Comment: No, it is located outside of wwwroot

Comment: what is "oustide of repo" exactly? which is the root of this repo?

Comment: The repo is 1click, the root is wwwroot/, in which all my files such as css, js, libraries and other files are located.

Comment: The root can't be wwwroot, as the .git folder is outside of it. The root is the level above wwwroot. I assume that what is "outside" is elsewhere, but I can't understand where is it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226983/discussion-between-oris-sin-and-daemon-painter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how big your files are but git normally is not meant to work with very large files.  I would suggest enabling lfs for .mp4 files

```
git clone git@gitlab.example.com:group/project.git
git lfs install                       # initialize the Git LFS project
git lfs track "*.mp4"
```

From github's page:

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

Basically, as is common with many databases, large binary files can create an issue and need a special case to help handle them.

More info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/) and [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/) and [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs).

Comment: They are between 550KB to 750KB. They are optimized exclusively to this size more or less so that they don't get bulky. Nevertheless, when I was working with Ubuntu and git, I didn't have any problem whatsoever. I would be able to add files inside my subdirectory, stage commit them easily. As I moved to Windows 10, its folder permissions of File Explorer is annoying me a bit...

Comment: Are they not showing up when you stage or just when you commit?

Comment: I did what you said  `git lfs install` and  `git lfs track "*.mp4" ` and it works like a charm!

Comment: Ok, it tracks the .mp4 files which were already there but whenever I am uploading new .mp4 files, they won't get tracked...

Comment: That's weird.  With the wildcard, I would think it would be aware of new files, too.  From the below answer, it looks like you may want to make sure that your .gitattributes file is updated.  Also, you can use the command 'git lfs ls-files' to list out your lfs tracked files I believe.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518688/git-lfs-refused-to-track-my-large-files-properly-until-i-did-the-following

Comment: Did you make sure to use the quotes when you specified "*.mp4"?  If you don't, your shell can expand the wildcard to the current specific files instead of maintaining the wildcard pattern?

Comment: I mismatched directories. Sorry, it was my bad after that... Everything is working as I said at the beginning. Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  FYI, if you'd like to learn more about LFS, Atlassian's quick tutorial is really nice
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs