# Git LFS Not Working Despite Following All Steps: pre-receive hook declined error; "You may want to try Git Large File Storage" suggested

Tags: git, github, hook, git-lfs

I first created the personal access github token and set the git remote url.  I then followed all the steps in the Git LFS command line instructions.

Ultimately, I get this error:

```
remote: error: Trace: 396225fe6f1f788b7923ed8938f0b6bbd8c7df6189e7f1b05ceab1af97160050
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File saved_model/variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001 is 134.40 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/pinzhi000/resp_db.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://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@github.com/pinzhi000/resp_db.git'
```

You can see exactly my command line inputs and outputs below:

[image]

I've looked at a bunch of stackoverflow posts related to this exact issue but none of them could resolve my error.

Comment: I have not actually used it, but you probably want [PeterD's `git lfs migrate` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65218535/1256452) from the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you already committed a copy of that file in past commits, you will need to rewrite said commits to replace direct blobs with `git lfs` links.