# What is the difference between git rm --cached and git reset <file>?

Tags: git

According to the [git rm documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm/),

```
--cached
Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index.    
Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.
```

But according to [this resource](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things/) unstaging a file is done with

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

What is the difference? Is there one?

Comment: `git reset` can be used to go back on the tree, for instance if you want to go two commits back you can do `git reset HEAD~2`.

Comment: If there is no `<file>` in `HEAD`, then both command equivalent. If there is `<file>` in `HEAD`, then `git reset HEAD <file>` will unstage file, while `git rm --cached <file>` will stage file for removal.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With `git rm --cached` you stage a file for removal, but you don't remove it from the working dir. The file will then be shown as untracked.

Take a test drive

```
git init test_repo
cd test_repo

touch test
git add test
git commit -m 'Added file test'

git rm --cached test

git status
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    test      <---- staged for removal

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        test              <-- still in the working dir
```

With `git reset <file>` you can unstage a file. In the example above you might want to use `git reset test` to unstage the removal.

```
git reset test
git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 21):

The command with flag `git rm --cached` removes the file from the index but leaves it in the working directory.  This indicates to `git` that you don't want to track the file any more.

On the other hand, the command `git reset HEAD <file>` leaves the file as a tracked file in the index, but the modifications cached in the index are lost.  This has the effect as if the file in cache had been over written by the file in HEAD (while the working tree file is untouched).

Answer (score 4):

clear cache full by this:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```