# What does --cached stand for with git?

Tags: git, github

I have one git command line like this

```
git rm -r --cached superlists/__pycache__
```

I know that the files would be removed,but are we creating temporary storage area?If yes,why?

Comment: Please have a look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001223/what-is-the-difference-between-git-rm-cached-and-git-reset-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rm --cached` — Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index. Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

for more see [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)