# Is there any reason why git-lfs might push more than the files size to github.com?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I wanted to get started working with `git-lfs` to push a 800+ MB binary to github.com for distribution. I'm seeing

```
> git push origin installer
Git LFS: (0 of 1 files) 65.72 MB / 860.12           Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Git LFS: (0 of 1 files) 1.03 GB / 860.12 MB
```

after

```
git lfs install
git lfs track [file]
git add [file]
git commit -m "[message]
git push origin [branch]
```

Is there any change that exceeding the size of the file is the expected behaviour/not a bug?

I'm considering splitting the binary into modules and keeping it below 100 MB, but the issue still makes me curious.

I'm aware of [how to work with large files on github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/).

I'm using `git-lfs` 1.5.3 on Ubuntu 16.10 and public github.com repositories.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git lfs - "this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330771/git-lfs-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00-mb)

Comment: How does that explain why 1.03 GB are pushed when the file is only 860 MB?

Comment: No idea but go with the docs and ask for github support for your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Progress meter duplicates bytes sent after retries. There's an open issue in Github :

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1542