# Failing to push to GitHub (this exceeds GitHub's file size limit)

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote

My local branch is not uploading to master because, as the error output states, "downloads/ue4-test-8.zip is 363.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB" I already removed this file and yet any commits I make get rejected.

- I've removed the large file.
- I thought everything would be fine so I added new files to the respiratory
- Now I get error when going to push about a file that doesn't exist

How can I resolve this problem and get back to pushing this repo?

Here is my output log:

```
~\Documents\GitHub\mryamz.github.io [master ↑6 +0 ~1 -0 !]> git push
Counting objects: 42, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 360.48 MiB | 668.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 42 (delta 18), reused 36 (delta 13)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (18/18), completed with 6 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 92c21619bdc53df9a9cf2ed2b801c3d5
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File downloads/ue4-test-8.zip is 363.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/mryamz/mryamz.github.io.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mryamz/mryamz.github.io.git'
~\Documents\GitHub\mryamz.github.io [master ↑6 +0 ~1 -0 !]> cd downloads
~\Documents\GitHub\mryamz.github.io\downloads [master ↑6 +0 ~1 -0 !]> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\mryamz.github.io\downloads


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/22/2017   4:58 PM          52509 Ampersand Studio v0.0.3.jar
-a----        1/11/2017   5:39 AM           3538 ascii_art .jar
-a----        7/26/2017   6:00 PM         133830 ClientSide.jar
-a----         3/3/2017   6:39 PM       69347251 Defend_The_Train.jar
-a----        1/11/2017   6:11 AM        2896549 Doppler_Effect.jar
-a----         1/9/2017   8:01 PM       10315457 friction_sim.jar
-a----        7/24/2017  11:45 PM         208804 jnativehook-2.1.0.jar
-a----        4/24/2017   9:15 PM         890923 Ludum_Dare_38.jar
-a----        4/23/2017   2:36 PM        1759272 Ludum_Dare_38_SRC.zip
-a----        5/12/2017  12:47 AM           6259 MBS.jar
-a----        2/18/2017   2:43 PM         226755 Pascals's Triangle.jar
-a----        2/18/2017   3:33 PM        1660624 Quadratic Calculator.jar
-a----        7/26/2017   5:27 PM          35977 RawPCM_Player.jar
-a----        1/11/2017   6:18 AM       10871259 Renassance v6.jar
-a----        2/16/2017   7:34 PM         116175 Scorched Earth.jar
-a----         5/8/2016   8:55 PM          18151 ServerSide.jar
-a----        7/26/2017   6:12 PM           9170 Simplix-Earth-Branch.jar
-a----        2/18/2017   2:38 PM          41453 Spirograph.jar
-a----        4/30/2017  12:44 PM         646609 sw.jar
-a----        1/11/2017   6:49 AM        1307614 Word Bank.jar


~\Documents\GitHub\mryamz.github.io\downloads [master ↑6 +0 ~1 -0 !]>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: Did you check the answer here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330771/git-lfs-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00-mb>?

Comment: The file _does_ exist...in your Git history.  Just because you removed the file currently does not mean that it is not there in the history.  Moral of the story: don't commit large binary files to your repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you have a commit with this file. Even if you delete the file and make a new commit, the file is persisted in a previous commit. And `git push` send all the missing commits to the remote.

You have to *rewrite git history* before pushing it. Without a `git log`, I can't help you with an exact command. [Squashing Commits](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_squashing) can do the job.

Comment: That link helped me figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue by the following:

1. git stash
2. git rebase -i
3. Then a text editor popped up and allowed me to write the term, "drop" next to the commit I needed to delete. The commit was deleted successfully.
4. git push

Comment: In a text editor I replaced word "pick" with word "drop"

Comment: How do I "confirm" after writing "drop" in the text editor? I keep hitting Enter and it is not working for me.

Comment: @Liz usually you press "esc" then `:wq` for save and exit the editor then press Enter.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD
git push
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: git push is not enough. I use `git push -f origin master ` which  forces to update the origin

Comment: this was the only answer that helped me solve this problem. finally I can push my files to the repo again.

Answer (score 7):

check if **Git LFS** installed
if not then got to https://git-lfs.github.com/ and download **Git extension for versioning large files**.

then run this command to install it after running the exe file downloaded.

```
git lfs install
```

after that use `git lfs migrate` command
in your case the command would be:

```
git lfs migrate import --include="*.zip"
```

and the push to remote using:

```
git push
```

Comment: `git lfs install`-->`git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: download from this link `https://git-lfs.github.com/` as mentioned. run it, then run these commands mentioned above.

Comment: - Homebrew user can run `brew install git-lfs` or macPorts user can run `port install git-lfs`.

Comment: Install Git lfs to your profile (not admin), start a new CMD prompt and then the command works. However, make sure you have backups of the large files as they dont get added to GIT!