# Can't push with Git-large-files

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have the file in my project, that more than 100 MB. 
I want to push it using git-lfs, but something went wrong and I receiving the same message from remote, that "this file exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB".

What I've done.

```
1. Downloaded git-lfs.
2. Installed it using brew.
3. Added files and patterns that should be tracked in the .gitattributes. 
4. Tried to push.
```

Now, my .gitattributes file have the following.

```
*.framework filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
ios/libs/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
ios/libs/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
GoogleMobileAds filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
ios/libs/ filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

I need to push ios/libs/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAd <- this file. And I tried to add it in various ways, but nothing helped.

Any ideas what I'm missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you already added the file and committed it, then deleted it and added it to git-lfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```
git add .gitattributes  isn't enough.
```

You need to push .gitattributes in order to be able to push large files to remote.

I reset my last commit, then added .gitattributes again and pushed it, after that, I was able to push the large file.

Thanks, @Sidharth Chhawchharia for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure .gitattributes is tracked. You could do it by using:

```
git add .gitattributes
```

In case it is an existing repository, please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633291/4190333

Comment: is this repository pre existing? I mean did you add git-lfs to an existing repo?

Comment: Yes. The repo exists already, and I want to push a large file first time.

Comment: In that case, please read this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633291/4190333

Comment: I solved my problem. 
git add .gitattributes  isn't enough.
You need to push .gitattributes in order to be able to push large files to remote.

I reset my last commit , then add gitattributes again and pushed it, after that I was able to push the large file. 
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, just configured git LFS with:

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
git config lfs.contenttype 0
```