# React Native: adding *.hprof to gitignore doesn't work

Tags: git, react-native, gitignore

I get a list of about 10 errors analogous to the following one when running `git push origin master`: `remote: error: File android/java_pid60072.hprof is 564.94 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330771/git-lfs-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00-mb) I added `*.hprof` to my .gitignore file. I then made some additional edits, did a commit, and it still generated this list of errors.

Why might my build be failing to ignore the hprof files? Here's the relevant section of my .gitignore:

```
# Android/IntelliJ
#
build/
.idea
.gradle
local.properties
*.iml
*.hprof
```

Comment: Did you completely remove `android/java_pid60072.hprof` from history? If not — do you understand it is stiil in some old commit(s)? Do you understand `.gitignore` doesn't ignore committed files?

Comment: No, I don't understand either. Can you explain, or point me to a resource?

Comment: I did run `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch android/java_pid60072.hprof`

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore : "*A `gitignore` file specifies intentionally **untracked files** that Git should ignore.*"

Comment: "*I did run `git filter-branch`…*" Please [edit] the question and that information. If the command doesn't work — perhaps wrong branch? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758 for alternatives and examples.