# Pushing an access database to a GitHub Repo

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push files to a github repo including an access database, however I get the following issue:

```
remote: warning: File AnyLogicDB.accdb is 61.40 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB

remote: error: Trace: 14017da929b66e7b755cf895f892372e0b7d0db9551c976c08fadb19d5f5b2fb

remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.

remote: error: File AnyLogicDB.accdb is 423.75 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

remote: error: File AnyLogicDB-Spot.accdb is 156.96 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

remote: error: File AnyLogicDB.accdb is 1218.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

remote: error: File AnyLogicDB.accdb is 1218.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

remote: error: File AnyLogicDB-Spot.accdb is 156.96 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '
```

Although the file is actually 400kB in size

Comment: Which file is actually 400 kB in size?

Comment: ....why are you storing `.accdb` files in Git? You shouldn't store large binary files in normal Git, instead you should use Git LFS - that's how you store large files.

Comment: AnyLogicDB.accdb and AnyLogicDB-Spot.accdb. It is not large anyways we just need it as a reference.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I suspect it's 400KB now after the OP clicked on _everyone's favourite_ toolbar button in MS Access: "Compact and Repair" - while the 1GB+-sized files would be the db file from earlier commits.

Comment: I did use Compact and Repair and they are both empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git lfs - "this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330771/git-lfs-this-exceeds-githubs-file-size-limit-of-100-00-mb)

Comment: The file is not large to go for this.

Comment: The current file size does not matter. What matters is the size of previously-committed files. Git stores every version of the file. If you committed a large file once and shrink it later, the large file is still stored in the commit history.

Comment: So the solution would be git lfs?