# Windows GUIs for git

Tags: windows, git, user-interface

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows) question, but it is a bit old now, and some of the answers seem outdated.

Question: please write one answer per GUI *you have used*, including pros and cons (for example, as far as I can tell, with git gui, you can't manage the stash).

Comment: This should be community wiki as there is no correct answer.

Comment: I use commandline for performing changes, and `gitk` for viewing the tree

Answer (score 3):

(This is not exactly a "Windows"  standalone Git GUI, but still quite advanced)

Considering that since then, Eclipse is in the process of mirroring all its [projects in Git repositories](http://dev.eclipse.org/git/), **[EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)** (based on [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)) have made some progress and are part of the Eclipse ecosystem, and is on par with [its Mercurial counterpart](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/).

You can [contribute to EGit there](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide).

This **[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html)** is quite complete.

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/images/github60.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/images/github60.gif)

Comment: wow, that gui is *very* confusing. I have no idea what's going on, and I'm a person who uses git from the command line, every single day!

Comment: There should be a "Simple" mode too, for the rest of us...

Answer (score 3):

So far I've been happiest with [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

Pros:

- Fairly complete access to git commands
- Doesn't hide git specifics like the index (unlike Tortoise)
- Good branch visualization
- Visual Studio integration in addition to standalone GUI or shell integration
- Actively developed

Cons:

- UI is rough around the edges in looks and usability.

Comment: I tried that too, but had some configuration problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605996/gitextensions-opens-winmerge-when-i-click-on-any-file-in-viewer) which I didn't manage to resolve (as often happens, I found something else which worked, so I didn't put too much effort into fixing the problem).

Answer (score 3):

As for the GitHub for Windows - I have used it for a little time and it's pretty nice. Very esthetic and quite straight forward. It's even better when working with repositories located on GitHub (however I used it with other targets as well).

Today I switched to completely new client for Windows made by Bitbucket named SourceTree. As I understand it's a port from Mac client and thanks to that it looks and feels great. It has LOADS of options and tools (I have not familiarized myself with many of them) and it's constantly developed ( http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/03/19/introducing-sourcetree-git-client-microsoft-windows/ ). They released the Beta version on 19.03.2013 and they have some really nice plans for future (Mercurial support as well!). I do think that it's worth a look.

Comment: SourceTree is only hosted by BitBucket. It is made by Atlassian - the same people who make JIRA amongst many other pieces of software.

Comment: You do not have to use BitBucket to use SourceTree afaik.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `Atlassian SourceTree`. It's a free Git Client for `Windows` & `Mac`.

I'm using it since the beta. And it's really the best tool ive ever used for git in my opinion.

[image]

[image]

Say goodbye to the command line – use the full capability of Git and Mercurial in the SourceTree desktop app. Manage all your repositories, hosted or local, through SourceTree's simple interface.

[image]

More informations under:

http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/03/19/introducing-sourcetree-git-client-microsoft-windows/
http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: I liked this one too. Easy for beginners. For the server with UI, check out http://bonobogitserver.com/ open-source under MIT license which makes use of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) for a few days now, and I have to say I'm very impressed. I'm not a git-genius, but so far I haven't had to break out the CLI for anything.

And the UI is just... pleasant, frictionless. There aren't any of the "couldn't they just have done this?" annoyances that I've found with others.

Comment: Looks attractive, but it's neither free nor open source. OTOH, I was looking for a TortoiseSVN-like tool for Git and this thread brought me right into [it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/484333/562776).

Answer (score 2):

Another option now is http://windows.github.com/ Github for windows. But only really if you are syncing with GitHub. I've been using this for a few weeks, and I do find I need to fire up a shell from time to time. Its also unclear what commands its actually issuing. I keep ending up in the middle of a broken rebase - but I have no idea why its rebasing! But for frictionless use 99% of the time its great.

Comment: It is possible to use Github for Windows with non-Github repositories ([as shown in an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905979/how-to-use-github-for-windows-2-0-with-non-github-repositories/26089104#26089104)), although you need to use the shell for the initial setup.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following

GitHub for Windows - required me to download installer which took a long time for me to install. UI was too basic for me and at that time was very slow even when using a local repository.

SourceTree - UI looks goods but under delivers on features when compared to GitEye and SmartGit.

Collabnet GitEye ([site](http://www.collab.net/products/giteye)) - UI is famililar to Eclipse users just like me. Worked great and especially had a credential store (SecureStore) which inspired some confidence in how it handles storing of passwords plus SSH key management.

SmartGit ([site](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/)) - offers personal and commercial versions but even the personal version is an absolute pleasure to use. Staging files, looking at logs, reverting, committing, pushing etc. The features were sufficient for me.

I'd recommend the last two especially SmartGit since the UI is user friendly and pushing to more than 1 repository is much easier.

My answer is not really that verbose but please try to download and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With visual studio there is http://gitscc.codeplex.com/ Git Source Control Provider which is a Visual Studio Extension. More into in this SO question [Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)