# How can I run 'git diff some/long/file/name' without typing the full path?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-diff, git-status

In my workflow, I often run the following pair of commands:

```
$ git status
M README.txt
M some/long/file/name
$ git diff some/long/file/name
```

Is there any way, for fast typing/use_shortcat for long file name without copying it name (this action require using mouse and it's no so fast like typing)?
Maybe something like `git diff $2`, where `$2` is second changed file from the status list...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git "shortcut" for filepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465269/git-shortcut-for-filepath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This tool (SCM Breeze)](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/scm_breeze) can do what you need, specifically see this part of the docs

> [image]
>   For example, if ga was your alias for git add, instead of typing
>   something like:
>
> ```
> $ ga assets/git_breeze/config* assets/git_breeze/install.sh You can
> ```
>
> type this instead:
>
> ```
> $ ga $e2 $e3 $e11
> ```
>
> But SCM Breeze aliases ga to the git_add_shortcuts
>   function, which is smart enough to expand integers and ranges, so all
>   you need to type is:
>
> ```
> $ ga 2 3 11
> ```

I think it suits your needs better than the solutions that are in the post I linked to in my comment above

Comment: Great! That I was need. Thank you very much, Tim.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this really looks usefull

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `*` placeholders as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20145909/302793). 
Usually you don't have to type the full name of the file like this

```
git diff -- **/name
```

Given that a short segment of the name, e.g. "na", is unique within the list of modified files, you can also do something like this:

```
git diff -- *na*
```

This way you don't have to count the entries to find out which number it is that you want to diff.

Answer (score 5):

Another way you can do it without installing a separate tool is to strip the output of git status, and pipe it through sed, then back to git diff. Its a long command, so you can put it in your .bashrc and alias it. For example, putting this in my .bashrc:

```
 myfunction() {
 git status --porcelain | sed -n "${1} s/^...//p' | xargs git diff
 }
 alias gd=myfunction
```

I can then do

```
>> git status
M main.cpp
M tipsy.cpp
M other.cpp
>> gd 2
```

And the output is git diff of the second file.

EDIT: I combined the two seds into one, because having two seperate ones was silly.

Comment: I've thinking about something like this. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found anouther way(But "SCM Breeze" is awesome and my primary tool): I'm using https://github.com/junegunn/fzf fuzzy-search with alias:

```
alias gfz="git status -s --porcelain  | cut -c 4- | fzf"
git diff $(gfz)
```

Answer (score -3):

Only:

```
git diff
```

Or:

```
git diff --cached
```

Then scroll with keyboard.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question, is not working when you edited lot of files

Comment: OK. I did not know this from beginning. It helped me for small changes.