# Best Mac OSX and Windows Git Clients, servers and diff tools?

Tags: svn, excel, git, version-control, vba

I am currently looking for git clients for Mac OSX,
I have tried the following:

- GitX (Didn't like it.. doesn't seem functional enough)
- Git Gui / GitK.. (***Butt*** Ugly! i mean yuuuuuck! and not user friendly)
- Source Tree (By far the best but still lacking somewhat)

Is there a functionally equivalent nice looking "versions" or "cornerstone" like client for git?
or a finder integration thing like toroisegit?

Also i need to either implement a locking system or find a diff tool for VBA in excel spreadsheets?

How can i do either of these?

Oh also is there a way of managing a git server (gitosis or other) with a gui?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: I see that you're a relatively new user; welcome! Your question is really about four questions in one. It's much better to ask a single, coherent question; if you have more than one, ask them separately. This will get you better answers (people looking at the title have no idea you have a VBA question) and make it easier for others to benefit (by searching for your question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best Git GUI on OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83789/what-is-the-best-git-gui-on-osx)

Comment: duplicates of your next question: [What GUIs exist for Git on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows) and [Windows GUIs for git (Updated)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763126/windows-guis-for-git-updated)

Comment: I don't think there's a duplicate question about gitosis/gitolite/general git server GUIs. As for your VBA question, it absolutely should be asked separately and in more detail - make it a bit clearer what your goal is. (Perhaps you want best practices for managing code which, brilliantly, is stored inside binary files, completely inaccessible to a VCS?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for the great answers!

In the end i went with:

- Tower - (Mac GUI).. It's freaking awesome! http://git-tower.com
- Gitorious (Central repo anagement server hosted on our own box) awesome.. but a SERIOUS pain to get running! http://gitorious.org [Heres](http://www.bluequartz.net/projects/ElectronicImaging/SCMService/html/gitorious___ubuntu__setup.html) the tutorial i used.

Works pretty well for us.. although i'd love to be able to buy a copy of Github FI but its V expensive :P

So i'll just use standard github for my open source repos!

Answer (score 1):

I have never found the need to manage a git server via the GUI since the server is just one big repo and the clients pull and push to it.  In my mind, there is no need for server management here but, we just barely scratch the GIT itch at our company currently.

As gui clients go give [gitbox](http://gitbox.pierlis.com/) a whirl.  The layout and design is very simple and easily "fades away" when you aren't pushing and pulling.  It is what many of us use, plus it is free

Comment: Thanks tried gitbox.. it's ok but pretty feature bare.. why isnt there a full client! may have to write one myself!

Comment: @Daniel: Because by and large, git users tend to find CLIs quite sufficient (and often much faster than GUIs). Please, no flamewars, this is just a broad generalization, not universal truth. If you do want to write one yourself, by all means, do - but you might want to use something like GitX as a starting point!

Comment: Thanks..Yeah i Hate Flamewars... I Actually Really Like the CLI My Colleges arent so Keen.. Am Gonna read through the GPL 2 in a while and see if i am allowed to fork gitx (maybe sell my changes.. i know thats not the open source spirit but a mans gotta eat!)

Comment: Full CLI here as well, I do understand the pain of trying to get colleagues working with it.  If you have a couple of noobs who you are trying to get going with Git then the simplicity of Gitbox should cover it.  Am I wrong?  

For the people who use Gitbox in our environment they rarely run into problems with its' simplicity.  Just my experience.

Comment: @Daniel: The general idea with the GPL, as far as you're concerned, is that you are perfectly welcome to fork gitx (though I would suggest simply contributing to it). This is really one of the two key ideas of the GPL - you're free to do what you want. The other idea, of course, is to protect the IP. It has to stay open source, under the GPL. You can sell copies, sure, but you also have to make the source freely available.

Comment: @Jefromi Yeah that's what I thought.. Any idea weather it counts to opensource some but keep some of my components closed source?

Comment: @Braden yeah thats a good point.. It's a shame there's not something like cornerstone for subversion.. But I guess subversions a lot less powerful so it'd be hard to get all the power into a slick UI

Comment: @Daniel: Anything which is derived from GPL-licensed material must be GPL'ed. Please don't try to evade this. (I also don't understand why you want to. You can get a lot of help, both in development and feedback, on an open source project that you'd never get on a closed source one. If your end goal is a GUI you're happy with, that's a very very good thing.)

Answer (score 1):

I too looked for a GUI for a while...but couldn't find anything I liked.  In the meantime I used the CLI and now I doubt I'd switch even if a good GUI became available.  With the CLI there is no waiting for a GUI app to load, no logging in, and it's just fast...exactly what I was looking for but didn't know it.

For managing a server, possibly...[Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious) or [Indefero](http://www.indefero.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at SCuMD git server (my branch). You can find it here:

https://github.com/OlegIlyenko/scumd

or just download distribution:

https://github.com/downloads/OlegIlyenko/scumd/scumd-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip

It has very little dependencies on environment - it even does not require git to be installed (but it needs Java)!

In order to install and use it just follow these steps:

1. Unzip
2. Execute `java -jar scumd-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. This will create default config in `~./scumd` folder
3. Now comes some configuration. Edit `~./scumd/scumd-config.xml` and make it fit your requirements. At the beginning it can look like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://asolutions.com/schema/spring/scumd" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://asolutions.com/schema/spring/scumd http://asolutions.com/schema/spring/scumd/scumd-0.1.0.xsd">
    <git-ssh-server port="1122" repositories-base="/home/YourUser/.scumd/git-repos">
        <default-server-key-pair />
    </git-ssh-server>

    <acl>
        <repository path="**/*.git">
            <groups allow="ReadWrite, Create" list="developers" />
        </repository>   
    </acl>

    <simple-user-dao>
        <group name="developers">
            <user name="user1" password="secret" />
        </group>
    </simple-user-dao>
</beans:beans>
```

Now run `java -jar scumd-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` again and git SSH server will start and listen port `1122`! You can login with `user1` that has password `secret`. Typical git URL looks like this:

```
ssh://localhost:1122/my-project.git
```

**More information about configuration and usage you can find in default config.**

I think it's good solution for the server (even if it does not have GUI). But it **much easier** to setup and configure SCuMD than other git servers out there (as far as I saw).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about a Diff Tool for VBA, you could try [VbaDiff](http://www.technicana.com/products/vbadiff.html). It's a tool I created for just this purpose, as I was having the same problems.