# git remote branch monitoring

Tags: git

I am working with a remote git repo that does NOT support email notification upon commit. I am wondering if anyone know any means/tools to monitor and track the commit on one or more branches?

Thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at SCuMD GIT Server. I described it's basic configuration here:

[Best Mac OSX and Windows Git Clients, servers and diff tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033528/best-mac-osx-and-windows-git-clients-servers-and-diff-tools/4775915#4775915)

It supports email-notifications (and a lot of other cool stuff like DB user authorization, independent SSH server, etc...).

Here is example config with e-mail notifications:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://asolutions.com/schema/spring/scumd" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://asolutions.com/schema/spring/scumd http://asolutions.com/schema/spring/scumd/scumd-0.1.0.xsd">

    <git-ssh-server port="1122" repositories-base="${gitRepos}">
        <default-server-key-pair />

        <listeners>
            <!--
                Email listener will send emails to provided email/users/groups(all users in each group) when event is triggered.
                Each configuration element can be defined either as attribute or inner tag.

                event attribute can have following values:
                    * authenticationSuccess
                    * authenticationFail
                    * authorizationSucces
                    * authorizationFail
                    * repoCreate
                    * pull
                    * push
                    * commit

                Note: If you want to use email listeners, you should also define <email-sender /> tag.
            -->
            <email event="push" emails="mu@email.com, hello@world.com" subject="My Notification!">
                <users>u1, u2</users>
                <groups>g1, g2</groups>
            </email>

        </listeners>
    </git-ssh-server>

    <!--
        If you are using email listeners, you should also define email-sender
        in order to define SMTP/SMTPS configuration
    -->
    <email-sender host="my.host" port="465" protocol="smtps"
                  auth="true" user="mailsUser" password="secret"
                  from="git@admin.com" replay-to="git@admin.com"
                  force-email="test@test.com" />

    <acl>
        <repository path="**/*.git">
            <groups allow="ReadWrite, Create" list="g1, g2" />
        </repository>
    </acl>

    <simple-user-dao>
        <group name="g1">
            <user name="u1" email="hello@test.com">
                <public-key file="/path/to/the/id_rsa.pub" />
                <public-key file="/path/to/the/other/id_rsa.pub" />
            </user>

            <user name="u2" email="u2@test.com">
                <public-key file="/path/to/another/key" />
            </user>
        </group>

        <group name="g2" />
    </simple-user-dao>
</beans:beans>
```

Server is still at beta stage, but it's fully functional and we using it at work (no problems yet).

Answer (score 4):

Fetch every other minute. If there are changes, react to them (send an email, for example).