# How to use GitHub for Windows 2.0 with non-GitHub repositories

Tags: github-for-windows

I just installed (as opposed to update) GitHub for Windows 2.0 and for the life of me I cannot find how to use it with non-GitHub repositories. In the past I have done this without issues using [this guide](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/30/using-github-for-windows-with-non-github-repositories.aspx/). However with version 2.0 the layout has changed and I cannot find a UI to clone a repo that is not from GitHub. I guess I have to drop to the command line but I have no idea how to use git that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, you can clone the repository with Git on the command line. To do so you can execute the following steps:

1. Start the Git shell (Start menu->GitHub, Inc->Git Shell on Windows 7, I'm not familiar with Windows 8 but I think it will show up when you type "Git Shell" on the start screen)
2. Make sure you are in the GitHub directory (C:\users\\Documents\GitHub). Otherwise use the `cd`-command to navigate there.
3. Use the clone command `git clone user@domain.com:/path/repository.git` with the clone-url for the project you want to add. ([More information about cloning](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository#Cloning-an-Existing-Repository))
4. Start GitHub for Windows and go to `tools and options->Options`
5. Click `Scan for repositories`, if everything went right your cloned project shows up.
6. Make sure it is selected and click `Add`