# How to use git as source control provider for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, git, ssms

Can we use GIT as the source control for sql management studio?

Comment: Don't know about git, but we are using VisualSVN for source control SQL Server scripts.

Comment: What did you end up doing?  It seems straightforward to track .sql files, whether in SMSS or MSVS, but what about solution and project files?

Comment: @tggagne currently what I did, is I track the sql scripts both the old and new one on a file system and track those files with GIT. I hope that are better way to do this on MS SQL management Studio. I am quite surprise that Microsoft do not provide this. I believe it will be easier for everybody, if they have the ability to track the changes of the stored proc and views or functions in MS Sql management studio it self.

Comment: Anyone notice that using SSMS's default encoding of UTF-16 won't let you use git diffs?

Comment: We've been using a third party product by red-gate for years. It does integrate limited git into management studio. By limited, for example, you cannot commit sql changes along side other code changes easily. Also, it seems to slow down significantly on larger dbs. 
see: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Comment: In my opinion, this question absolutely *does not* violate Stack Overflow guidelines and should be opened. The OP is not seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc, but asking about the capabilities of a well-established tool used by virtually every programmer. The question's high score indicates that the community sees it as a good, relevant question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

for Database source control within SSMS

Agent SVN - SCC Subversion Plug-in.
http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/ssms/ms_ssms.html

or

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I’ve found out that ApexSQL has a tool that natively supports Git as a source control system. It comes as a SSMS add-in, and offers a wizard you can use to map database objects with the source control systems. To do that:

1. Download and install [ApexSQL Source Control](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_source_control.aspx)
2. Start SSMS and in Object explorer select the database you want to be linked to a source control
3. Right-click the database, and form the context menu, select the Link database to source control option, from the ApexSQL Source Control submenu
4. Select the source control system (in your case it is Git) and choose from 2 database development models - shared or dedicated. Shared model is recommended when you link a database on which multiple developers will work at the same time
   [image: Database development model - choose between shared or dedicated]
5. Filter objects which you don’t want to track using source control: by schema, type or name by schema, type or name
6. Provide appropriate login information and repository string. For Git it is: 
   `<protocol>://<hostname>:<portnumber>/<Git server name>/<repository>` (see example below):
   [image: Log into Git source control system]

More detailed step-by-step instructions can be found in this article: 
http://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/link-database-source-control-system-2/

Answer (score 9):

Try `sql-source-control`, a free and open source CLI used to get SQL into source control systems like Git.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-source-control

Comment: This is an impressive initiative but this package cannot be used cause of the bug when index has multiple attributes

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft has released [SQL Operations Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/what-is). It's a free tool that runs on Windows, macOS, and Linux, for managing SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Data Warehouse; wherever they're running. It comes with [native GIT support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/source-control).

Comment: Currently called Azure Data Studio. It inherits its native GIT support from Visual Studio Code. Correct me if I am wrong but it doesn't version directly your selected (database) Stored Procedures, Functions, .. to git repo. It is using its git support for plain files.

Comment: Correct it uses plain files, it doesn't support native database versioning.

Comment: I gave it a try. It has a promising future, being FOSS in active development with free extensions, while SSMS add-ons are almost always pricey. Unfortunately, for source control, it is much worse than generating scripts in SSMS and using source control externally as I'm doing now with git-gui. In ADS, there is no way to export multiple objects at once to individual files where even the built-in source control can read them. Each object must be opened as script, then go to Explorer and right click the open editor to save as file, then add to source control.

Comment: They have made some more progress on it as of 2021, but have a huge backlog. Again, promising future, but nowhere near capabilities SSMS has.

Comment: looks like it's only for SQL on Azure

Comment: @MC9000, Azure Data Studio works with lots of relational and NoSQL database, including SQL Server, Azure SQL, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, MongoDB. There are free extensions for all sorts of stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You could add [Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807485/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-git-bash) as an External Tool (Tools | External Tools...):

- Name: &Git (use `&` to specify a hot key)
- Command: `C:\windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` (32-bit Command shell)
- Arguments: `/c ""C:\path\to\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`  [Finding the path where Git is installed on a Windows system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507368/finding-the-path-where-git-is-installed-on-a-windows-system)
- Initial directory: `$(ItemDir)`

Comment: Or just Git Bash from a command line.  It's not so bad.

Comment: I assume this doesn't magically make Git able to track SQL objects as if they were files.  Can you elaborate on what this actually does?

Answer (score 3):

Since SSMS is (more or less) a custom version of Visual Studio, you might be able to use a solution intended for VS:

[Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)

Alternatively, manage your DB source code in Visual Studio from the beginning, not in SSMS. That way (at least in VS2010) you have database projects, integrated deployment and unit testing etc. Or continue using SSMS and check in your code from an external tool when you're ready (not so convenient, of course).

But it depends on exactly what you're doing: SSMS is a DBA tool, VS is a developer tool. Either way, you should be using some form of source control, but it's not clear from the question exactly what sort of files you need to version.

Answer (score 3):

Not yet but if you go to http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/39019-sql-source-control/suggestions/537681-add-git-support and vote for redgate to add support for git it might get added in the next version. Yes I know it's a commercial product but some products are just good enough to pay for!

Comment: Regate source control now support git

Answer (score 3):

Red Gate SQL Source Control has been updated to include Git and Mercurial support (as well as Perforce and TFS). Be forewarned that their DVCS integration is not 100% feature complete in relation to their SVN product, as basic features such as viewing history of an object are not supported from within SSMS. This may be a deal-breaker if other Red Gate tools like SQL Compare are part of your workflow.

Our workaround was to install TortoiseGit or GitExtensions and navigate to the repository on disk to drill into the specifics. It works but is a bit clunky.

Answer (score 3):

VersionSQL is an SSMS source control add-in I've designed to be lightweight and easy to use.  In the Object Explorer panel, just right-click on a database or object and click Commit.  VersionSQL will script it out to Git/SVN in a neatly organized folder structure.

Check it out at [https://www.versionsql.com](https://www.versionsql.com/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=3793388)

Comment: I prefer this answer because it easy to use, built in ssms and relatively cheaper...

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of answers around this question which you might want to look at but in a nutshell ....

The nature of version control is to store the original file and then the deltas, the difference between the original file committed and and subsequent changes (ok i have made that a bit simpler than it is perhaps) and then to manage the version number and give tools to extract any particular revision you need. This also then allows you to compare previous revisions and roll back (etc. etc.)

The RDBMS is made up of the schema and the and data these change and can change frequently in the case of the data so even if you did VCS what would you compare to do a restore and how would that help? Assuming you have a live system then reverting to an earlier revision would lose all the data stored in the interim and although i have never tried it i suspect could destroy the general integrity of the RDBMS.

The better solution is to use a backup application built for that RDBMS, MySQLdump say in the case of MySQL which makes a snapshot of the data and the structure of the data and store that in a safe place.

Dumps can be scheduled regularly and you can do things like master/slave databases (or other strategies) so you can backup live production databases on the fly without impacting on performance

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about source control for DDL and scripts, not how to backup a complete database.

Comment: Yes looks like it my apologies, so he is asking how to source control an application?

Comment: it's also not true that the nature of version control, in general, is to store the original file and then the deltas. that's not how git works, for one.