# How to add git bash to already installed TortoiseGit

Tags: git

I have already installed TortoiseGit but I don't have Git Bash as an option, can anyone advise me how I can install this?

Comment: Can you not just reinstall TortoiseGit?

Comment: If you have installed TortoiseGit, you should also have installed msysGit (as it is a prerequisite) which comes with a git bash. Check in the Start menu for the shortcut to start it.

Comment: You will probably need to copy your keys to a place that git-bash will recognize: http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Comment: Are you sure you dont already have it installed? Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8507368/1380061

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and download Git bash form http://git-scm.com/downloads , however if you use a key instead of a user id password , you might need to re configure.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Git for Windows, and enable `Git Bash Here`, see:

[image]

Then, there will be a context menu item `Git Bash Here` when right clicking in the folder, see:

[image]

---

Or you can use the one in Start menu, see:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the "Git Bash Here" option only a windows shell (right click content menu) option to open bash terminal? (And not the actual bash executable)?

Comment: Yes, to open bash terminal. Updated my answer.