# Run `sox` command line program with foreach?

Tags: powershell

I have a zip file, with lots of directories and files. Somewhere are `.vox` files.

I have script in PowerShell that unzips and finds all `.vox` files.

Than I have command line program `sox`, which can convert vox file to mp3. But it works only in cmd.

```
sox -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law inputfile outputfile
```

Is possible run this command under PS with `inputfile` and `outputfile` variables, so I can use sox with a lot of vox files? Maybe `foreach`?

Comment: &"xxx\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe" "-t" "raw" "-r" "8000" "-e" "a-law" "$way.vox" "$way.mp3"

Comment: If you've got a script already, it's best to include its code so we can see what you're doing. If you edit your question to include this you'll get a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$sourceDirectory = "C:\voxfiles"
$destinationDirectory = "C:\soxfiles"

# Grab the list of files
$voxFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDirectory -Filter "*.vox"

# Loop over the files
foreach ($voxFile in $voxFiles) {
    $inputFile = $voxFile.FullName
    $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationDirectory -ChildPath $voxFile.Name

    # Call CMD
    & "Sox -t raw -r 8000 -e a-law $inputFile $outputFile"
}
```

### [Running CMD command in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940243/running-cmd-command-in-powershell#24941189)

Comment: Don't think the `$()` in `a-law $() $inputFile $outputFile` is actually required?

Comment: Well spotted @JamesC. - that was a remnant from a quick refactor for clarity!