# How to run cmd in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

How to run cmd command in powershell? I have this command in cmd:

```
licenseassistant /request:"C\User\temp" /batch
```

How to do this in powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running CMD command in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940243/running-cmd-command-in-powershell)

Comment: Just run the exact same command in powershell ad You're good to go

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, I often use **cmd /c** .

Therefore you should be able to run:

```
cmd /c licenseassistant /request:"C\User\temp" /batch
```