# Powershell not finding PNPUTIL when script launched from shortcut

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script to install TCP/IP printers on Windows 10 that uses PNPUTIL to load drivers. When the script is run from a Powershell window, everything works great.

When I launch the script from a shortcut using the format

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file MyScript.PS1
```

I get an error 'The term 'pnputil.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program' when PNPUTIL is called. The rest of the script runs fine.

Relevant code:

```
Write-Host `n 'Installing printer driver..'
pnputil.exe /add-driver "\\myServer\HP UPD PCL 5\hpcu180t.inf"
```

Any ideas as to why this won't work when launched from a shortcut?

EDIT:I tried using

```
& pnputil.exe /add-driver "\\myServer\HP UPD PCL 5\hpcu180t.inf"
```

as referenced in

[Running CMD command in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940243/running-cmd-command-in-powershell)

but I still get the error. I also tried

```
start-process pnputil.exe /add-driver "\\myServer\HP UPD PCL 5\hpcu180t.inf"
```

but got a similar error that pnputil.exe could not be found.

Both of these options work from a Powershell prompt, but again, fail when launched from a shortcut.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running CMD command in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940243/running-cmd-command-in-powershell)

Comment: try to specify full path to  pnputil.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're invoking a *32-bit instance* of PowerShell** on a 64-bit system, and that instance doesn't see `pnputil.exe` (by filename only).

Instead of:

> ```
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file MyScript.PS1
> ```

use:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file MyScript.PS1
```

- Folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` is where the 32-bit executables live.
- Paradoxically, for historical reasons, it is `C:\Windows\System32` that houses the 64-bit executables.

---

If, for some reason, you do need to run a 32-bit instance of PowerShell, you can invoke `pnputil.exe` by its full path:
It only exists as a 64-bit executable in the 64-bit system folder, which 32-bit processes can access as `C:\Windows\SysNative`:

```
C:\Windows\SysNative\pnputil.exe
```