# Visual Studio Code PIP command doesn't work properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used command in terminal pip install --upgrade pip and after that I cant use PIP command in Visual Studio Code.

Here is what I get when try to use PIP command:
[Error in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcc69.png)

I tried to reinstall VS Code, but didnt work.

Comment: this is powershell and not dos commandshell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running CMD command in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940243/running-cmd-command-in-powershell)

Comment: No, it dosent :(

Comment: can you elaborate why it doesn't help

Comment: same error as I described in question (image).

Comment: your image shows no error, that makes it impossible to help so i run  `C:\Users\nbk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` and it run with out problems, you code produced a lot of them some more detailed error

Comment: further your ciomand wih pyhon-csv can not be run in python 3.11, but basocally there is really nothing wrong installing other  pip packages, as long as they are compatible

Comment: Its not about python-csv, I cant run pip command at all in VS

Comment: Start the terminal and run pip it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not a vscode error. Reinstalling vscode should not help. You can try reinstalling python.

[image]

Or you can add the full python path to the command like

```
E:\Desktop\project\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: Tried to reinstall python, same issue. :(

Comment: What if you use an absolute path command?

Comment: like from website copy command?

Comment: As in my answer. Modify the Python path to the path on your machine.

Comment: Thank you, it works. One dummy Q, how to make it to be default? I mean, in next installs I want use pip install numpy, not E:\Desktop\project\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy?

Comment: If you are using a general python environment, configure the system environment variable `path`. If you use a virtual environment, just activate the environment in the terminal (select the virtual environment interpreter in vscode, and then creates a new terminal and the environment will be automatically activated).

Comment: I am using VS code for python. Should I configure in general variables in windows ?
I will check as solved.