# Can't run ping or other commands in Windows Powershell

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I am having trouble using windows powershell. System level commands as well as installed program commands do not seem to be working:
[attempting to use ping and java --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deovf.png)

I have tried manually adding to the path via powershell:
`$env:Path += ";C:\Windows\System32"`

I have verified the file locations are correct:
[System 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeaXW.png)

and java:
[Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTEOe.png)

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Looks like a system issue rather than a programming issue, so probably a question better suited to Super User.

Comment: You are trying to run a cmd.exe command in PS.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940243/running-cmd-command-in-powershell