# demystify source version control  with visual studio 2010

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, git, version-control, mercurial

**Update**

So in my Original question I was just frustrated because I was being pushed to use source control but I just couldn't understand it (after using SVN & VSS).

I meandered a little bit, and after visiting it a few times, decided to read http://www.hginit.com and it practically was my salvation.

**DCVS**, (atleast for me being a single dev) just makes sense, and I understood source control. DCVS is the *way/philosophy* that both GIT and Mercurial Operate on, I guess they both are very similar, **however**, GIT is not evolved on Windows, Mercurial however has good tools @grenade has mentioned all of them in his answer. The installs were painless and I'm working very happily now.

Also, I use [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) which is mercurial based and pretty awesome! =D

Read http://www.hginit.com the WHOLE thing, even if you think it might not apply to you!

[Check out Linus Torvalds Talk on Git.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8) - Generally amusing and you understand what DCVS is. This [Stackoverflow Blog article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/) might be helpful.

Note, http://www.codeplex.com and http://code.google.com/projecthosting/ both support mercurial

Also see : [idiots checklist for mercurial with visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447987/idiots-checklist-for-mercurial-with-visual-studio-2010)

---

**Original Question:**
Lord all I ask is for some simple software that will maintain versions of my files and revert to ones I want.

Personally, I felt like just using a nice backup tool I have to just zip up a copy of my folder on another drive when I want. But they said I Have to use SOME source versioning.

Already posted the problem I had with SVN. Now its GIT.

I downloaded msysgit preview 1.7.2.3 from here http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/
Then GIT Extensions from the code.google.com
Then I downloaded p4merge from here : http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/index.html

I have Win7 x64 with VS2008. I see the GIT menu in VS, but nothing happens!? Jeez!

Worst, where are the docs? Whats Bash, Stash, Cherry Pick? Anything I click on the VS GIT toolbar or the Git Menu in VS does not do anything! I downloaded the complete setup : http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/downloads/detail?name=GitExtensions203SetupComplete.msi&can=2&q=
BUT I dont see KDiff3 anywhere on my pc? p4merge itself has its own problems asking me for some server address for config when I want everything local!

**Could someone PLEASE suggest something hideously simple**
I dont do big projects, mostly all in house utilities, I'm a one man team and I like to keep it simple.

**NOTE: I need something that works with Win7x64 and VS2010, vs2008 is on my home PC but VS10 on the dev box**

Comment: See [
Using Git with Visual Studio
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio).

Comment: GIT isn't exactly simple source control. How about using Visual SourceSafe? I don't think it gets much simpler and it is from the same vendor as Visual Studio. There is a fix to integrate it with VS2010: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB976375.

Comment: Although we are using Visual Sourcesafe for 10 years without problems, it doesn't have a very good reputation. Many people reported corrupted repositories over time. My main reason not to recommend it though is because it's obsolete.

Comment: true, I have seen a friends VSS repository get corrupt. But it seemed nice and likable, plus no headaches installing. If the repository gets corrupted, does VSS leave the current dir alone. What SVN did what mess with the directory where my solution was, and I lost 4 files (I guess it was my fault installing it) But does VSS also mess with the current dir and solution? If the repository gets corrupted is everything lost?

Comment: @Lieven: Yes, VSS is obsolete, but if all you want is a simple editing history with very good VS integration I would say VSS is a nice alternative. I don't know about repository corruption, but that could be a problem. If you want branching and atomic changesets you should look somewhere else, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: no branching no atomic chagesets(dont know what that is) I need : Commit, Revert, view all commits THATS ALL!

Comment: VSS is plenty if that's all you need but still Git, Mercurial and the like are also easy enough (with tortoise integration) for that. AMOF, it's so convenient, I find myself creating a git repository when I start editing a photo in Photoshop or even my daughter when she is working on a school project.

Comment: VSS is plenty if you don't mind corruption...

Comment: =) Thanks! I began reading this, http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html It actually explains source control. I understand well how teams would need this but I still dont see any benefit of using Src ctrl for ME because the subject is so loosely explained, Im just messing up all the time. I played with GIT and now I have some branch somewhere, and it keeps telling me messages I dont understand at all. Compared to using a simple differential backup tool I dont see what I'm losing and/or gaining.(For MY SITUATION) Feels lot like over complication to me.

Comment: I am still undecided about src ctrl for my next project, its the biggest Ive done yet, ~15000-25000 lines I estimate to give you an idea. (Asp.net, silverlight, win forms). I am doing it all alone, I have to make 2 mockups before kicking off so I'm thinking using SrcCtrl for those and see how it goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[hginit](http://hginit.com) is a very simple tutorial that will show you a simple way to manage your source code.

Git is a good one but I don't use it so I don't know what's gone wrong. I use [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) with [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) and some private repositories on [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/). Joel's tutorial at [hginit.com](http://hginit.com) explains everything you need to know.

Comment: +1, read OP's question about Subversion and suspect he's doing something wrong, but if he'd really rather not use it, I'd recommend Mercurial and hginit too.

Answer (score 2):

I got confused about the installation process myself the first time around. Uninstall Git, P4Merge and Git Extensions, then run the "complete" MSI again. On the second page of the installer, press the Install Git button, then once that is complete, press the Install Kdiff button and accept the defaults, then proceed with the Git Extensions. You can accept the default on every option.

All the parts will then be automatically configured to work together, and the buttons and context menu items will work.

Good version control systems are inherently slightly complex because they do a very sophisticated job, so you have to approach them in the same way as any complex tool - start with a handful of simple functions and ignore all of the other stuff for now. Git Extensions includes a manual that shows you the basics (Start > Program Files > Git Extensions > User Manual).

Mercurial is a little more friendly, but I'm reluctant to recommend it because (sadly) it seems to have lost the popularity contest. If you want to work with other developers on projects outside of a corporate environment, it's increasing likely that you will be using Git.

Comment: hi tried that. When I run the complete install, when I click KDiff3 nothing happens, and there no kdiff.exe on my pc. When I click MsysGit I get this error: http://www.mediafire.com/imgbnc.php/060b2e3d53ada602cb006f560f77c71f6g.jpg

Comment: So I played with it, I can see how to commit. I dont get the part about staging files? I have to stage all files before a commit? Also, to revert to a previous commit I click Git->View Changes->Right Click and select Checkout Revision. Is that how its done??

Comment: Yes, each commit only contains the changes that you have decided to stage - this give you exact control. If you stage a directory, all of the changes to things inside the directory are staged, so you don't need to pick files one-by-one unless you want to.

Comment: If you use checkout on files then their working copies are changed to match the state of the revision that you specified. There are several ways to get at this. Git Extensions also puts right-click options into VS that lets you revert selected files to the latest commit (throwing away uncommitted changes). I actually use that feature a lot, much more often than I go back to previous commits.

Comment: @stuart: with regard to popularity of hg vs git, seems like mercurial is trending up... at least on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995636/popularity-of-git-mercurial-bazaar-vs-which-to-recommend

Comment: Retype of the solution to the install problem: I ran command prompt as admin,ran the installer from the command line, everything installed perfect after that! Another option is to disable UAC

Comment: On last question, commit only seems to work when I select a project in the solution explorer. Not when I select the whole solution, do I have to commit each project separately, no other options?

Comment: @radman: Interesting - I wonder if the increase here is partly a result of Kiln, or if Mercurial has been picked over Git in closed environments? Git (and GitHub) now seem to becoming standards for almost all of the Open Source projects and communities that I look at regularly, so using it feels inevitable to me. For example it's entrenched in Fedora, Debian, Ruby and Clojure, getting there in .NET Open Source, PostgreSQL migrated recently, and Mozilla have just put a project on GitHub (despite being a Mercurial shop).

Comment: @Gideon - if you select a project in the Solution Explorer and press Commit then the Commit window displays unstaged and staged changes from all of the projects (and any changes to the solution itself). I don't know this why doesn't work if the solution is the current selection.

Answer (score 1):

[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) is hideously simple.

Bash is just using git at the command line.
I wouldn't bother to much with Stash/Cherry pick when you are just getting your feet wet.

Once you've installed TortoiseGit, you can administer your repository in Windows Explorer. Creating a repository and commiting your first (and next) version to it is "a snap".

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone tried SmartGit?

I'm sure that as far as converting to Git (instead of say, SourceSafe), it's a just do it and eventually it'll get easier kinda deal.  But, it's Linux roots are an obstacle.  I'd like a real straightforward and uptodate book or online doc on How To Use Git on Windows!

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a complete fanboy, I'd recommend that you check out Git Extensions. It bundles a stand-alone GUI, Visual Studio integration and some shell integration so you don't have to use the command-line shell until you want pretty advanced or obscure features. The included manual covers the basics well, and IIRC the screencasts linked to on the project site were straightforward.

Comment: Why is Git's Linux roots an obstacle? It works fine on Windows.

Comment: @M Noreen : I feel your plight, there isn't anything on all the options on Git, but GitExtenions is good stuff, only known issues (like i had) while installing on Win7 otherwise I was up and running really quick =)

Comment: I'm using SmartGit at home and at work. It really is very good. I don't think it 'protects' you from having to understand git, but it does mean you don't have to remember all the command line syntax. I gave up on Visual Studio integration a while ago, it just isn't conceived so great for edit-merge-commit source control.

Comment: Thanks everyone, we finally just jumped in. Using Git Extensions and Git Bash, and am getting used to it. It's definitely a "why didn't I do this sooner" kinda thing, but there's also much more still to learn!