# File Based Version Control System with VS2010 Integration

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I'm looking for a source control system that I can use for personal projects. I have two laptops and a desktop I develop on and a flash drive for portability. Rather than keeping all my code on my flash drive I want to check it out / in on the machine I'm working on at the time.

I'm specifically looking for something file based that integrates with VS2010, *not* an internet / network / server based source control system.

I was hoping for something free, but could afford something reasonably cheap.

Any thoughts?

Regards

Tristan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/) seems to have support for Visual Studio 2010 and is a breeze to use. As far as SVN itself goes, it does not need a server to operate: it can work off USB drive just fine.

Remember to back your flash drive, though.

Comment: Nice. I tried GIT, but after about 6 hours, gave up and found SVN to do the job much better. :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [GIT](http://git-scm.com/)?

It is a distributed SCM, meaning there is no server.

As for using it with visual studio - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio) SO question and answers.

Comment: Git, or any other DVCS, like Mercurial, Bazaar. There's nice UI for Mercurial called TortoiseHG.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're looking for [Plastic SCM Community Edition](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/11/building-plastic-scms-community-with.html).

- It is totally [integrated with Visual Studio](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/11/plastic-307-is-out.html)
- [Shell Extension](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/shell-extension-tour.html) too (like TortoiseSVN and so on)
- Check the [branch per task cycle](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/08/branch-per-task-workflow-explained.html)
- [Diff and merge tools](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/07/move-support-in-diff.html) with refactor support

So definitely something to look at.