# Good version control system when doing ASP.NET development on windows?

Tags: .net, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327918/free-source-control)

Hey, I'm looking for a good version control system in .net.

Here is a list of requirements:

1. I need to share code with other developers
2. I want to go backwards when I found a problem at some point
3. It should be easy to use and free to download, I cannot afford TFS

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with Mercurial using [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org). I love the notion of changesets instead of versions, and it makes merging a breeze. You should check out the [HgInit tutorial](http://hginit.com/) to decide for yourself. Bitbucket has an integrated issue tracker and wiki, which I love (and is free for 5 users). There is a great plugin called [HgScc](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html) for integration inside Visual Studio. If you have no loyalties to existing source control, Mercurial is a great place to start.