# Solution to adding a Git (TortoiseGit) toolbar to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tortoisegit

Anyone know how to create a toolbar in Visual Studio 2010 to use with Git (TortoiseGit)?

Thanks

SurfRat

Comment: This is a site for asking questions, not for posting "how to configure VS" tips.

Comment: This is the wrong way to get your reputation above 10. Asking a question might be a better means. Just sayin'

Comment: Don't hesitate to copy/repost "my" answer, making it yours. I will then delete my post. In the meantime, this is how you can contribute to SO while respecting the spirit of Q&A: with a question and an answer ;) (since it is ok to [answer one own's question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it))

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to be a question. I will post the answer in the morning as I can't reply to my own answer for 7 hours.

Comment: I just deleted my answer, and re-formatted yours.

Comment: Thanks for help... new to stackoverflow.

Comment: you might try this too: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Puvox.tortoisegit-buttons-in-vscode

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[image]

I wanted a Git toolbar in Visual Studio and I found no solution to this so I thought I would share this with you.

I installed the [**Git Source Control Provider**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c/) and got Git working (via TortoiseGit) with the right click context menu. This was tedious and rather ugly as all the TortoiseGit commands had the same icon.

I then added external tools to Visual Studio...

[image]

[image]

The external tool commands for TortoiseGit are as follows:

```
Title: Git Push
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:push

Title: Git Commit
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:Commit

Title: Git Sync
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:Sync

Title: Git Revert
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:Revert

Title: Git Log
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:Log
```

Once the external commands were created I created my toolbar. Visual Studio 2010 out of the box will not allow you to have an image in your toolbar so I installed the **[Command Image Changing Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/17/command-image-changing-extension.aspx)**.

Here are the icons I created
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The end result is a toolbar with the commands (showing only icons) that I need.

**Update for Visual Studio 2012**

The commands have changed slightly and are as follows:

```
Title: Git Commit
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:commit

Title: Git Push
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:push

Title: Git Sync
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:sync

Title: Git Compare
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe
Arguments:  /path:"$(ItemPath)" /command:diff

Title: Git Revert
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:revert

Title: Git Log
Command: C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe
Arguments: /path:"$(SolutionDir)" /command:log
```

Comment: I had to make a few modifications to the tool commands.  The command for me was C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe and the arguments for the /command: switch needed to be all lower case.  Worked great otherwise!

Comment: No Images for VS2012? :(

Comment: What about `push --all`?