# Tools to work with visual studio project on server?

Tags: visual-studio

i want tools like Team foundation or SVN subversion to work with the team in same project by putting source project on the server. i want program that do it but i don't want svn and team foundation . are there another tools like them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's GIT, it's nearly like SVN but its not :O http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)

A good online website for this would be https://github.com/

Comment: can u give me list of these tools?

Comment: I use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio but there are many other solutions like this little list http://git-scm.com/tools