# How to work on a single project via adhoc wireless in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

my team is working on a project but we figured out if we continue, committing the changes we're making will be different. The option we're considering is to share the project on an adhoc wireless connection and work on it together but I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this, like one that will allow you see that a different user is working on a class when you open it (like Google Documents) etc.. Thanks.

ps: I'm looking into the Team Foundation Server, but it sounds a bit complex, though I'm downloading the trial now, I don't know if it's what I'm looking for...

Comment: have you considered using Mercurial ? http://mercurial.selenic.com/ I dont understand why you would have an issue with having someone else working on the same file as you, thats what merging is for?

Comment: Try the free [TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express), a lightweight platform tightly integrated with VS (currently in beta)

Comment: @wal I didn't say I have an issue with that, I'll just like to know when someone else is working on the same page as me.

Comment: @KMoraz, thanks I'm looking into it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIT, GIT, GIT.

GIT is a simple free solution to this problem.  It merges files modified by multiple users very well.

[GIT with VS.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio)

[GIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)

Comment: Funny enough, though not the answer, this was the best alternative I could find.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MSDN account install Team Foundation Server in Basic configuration or do what KMoraz told you: use TFS Express (it's still a beta, but it's "go live" so don't be afraid to use it). You can install both version on any kind of computer (yours for instance but it will have to be started all the time your teammates are working).

I strongly encourage you to give a try to tfspreview.com (Team Foundation Services) which is the cloud version of TFS, it's free for now (as long as it's beta) but Microsoft always said that it won't cost a lot when going retail.

Team Foundation Services is really great, you know have continuous integration in the cloud, it's pretty nice. I can give you more info about it if you're interested.