# Replicating Local Subversion to remote Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control

We're using Subversion locally at our development server. We need to provide access to our clients of the same. This can be achieved by making the server publishing it on the web, but we do not want to publish it due to some other reasons I don't want to disclose.

What I'm interested to know is that, whether I can host another instance of Subversion on internet server at some hosting company data center for reliability and easier maintenance, and make both of the instances of subversion to talk to each other to synchronize the changes.  I have heard about replicating subversion repository/server, and would like to know how this needs to be setup? And more importantly, Is it a right solution to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your clients just need to read the repository, another instance of Subversion with [SVN Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) could help you.

Comment: I have gone through it, but didn't get an idea as how it would help me! Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using **bazaar** (TortoiseBzr) for this.

1. Checkout your local SVN project with bazaar. This will convert it to BZR format
2. Push it to your SVN server
3. Voilà :)

Using BZR on SVN:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-svn-projects.html

I've mentioned bazaar, but I'm sure you can do this with other distributed VCS as git, mercurial ...

Comment: this looks promising, but I didn't find any tool to integrate bazaar with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Have a look to this answer about git integration in visual studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio

Comment: @Krunal Did you import your project to Git repository, and now work only on Git ? Or did you synchronize SVN repo with Git push command to SVN repo ?

Comment: For older projects we still use SVN, but all newer projects we switched to Git. We plan to make 100% migration although for all projects. We didn't used Git push command to SVN repo.