# Git and shared projects

Tags: visual-studio, git, version-control

I'm new to Git. I work in Visual Studio.

```
Solution
- Phone App, refs Orange and Cabbage
- Shared Lib Orange
- Shared Lib Strawberry
- Shared Lib Cabbage, refs Strawberry
```

Each of these should be in different repositories. I'd like the shared libs to trigger builds on TeamCity that publish them on NuGet so my other apps update from the feed when they're built next.

Is there a special way to manage this in Git or shall I just pull them all into the App solution and run a batch file to commit them all together?

I have yysun's Git add-in installed in the VS IDE but it only controls the app's repo, so I will have to setup a macro or pin a taskbar button to commit on all repos.

My question is this: considering the normal everyday-ness of this arrangement, is there not some simple setup I can do in Git to support this without having to spend 20% of my programming day issuing DOS commands in the right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) could be a good solution.

Comment: I tried to read the documentation on this before posting the question but it was hard to understand and looked like a complete PITA and that I might have to use branches for all development. I just can't understand why no source control system can manage anything more complex than 10 text files in a single folder.

Comment: I've read that git submodules aren't that easy, but trust me git can manage a lot more than 10 text files ;-)

Comment: So I have to have 4 DOS windows running to commit on each repo 10 - 20 times a day, and for my home projects I will have to setup a Git server. So my VS IDE is 2012 and then I step back to 1970 to manage my source code. But thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Marked as answer. Submodules seem to be the way, but I'm realising there's still no perfect VCS yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Using Git with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio).

Also, if your workflow lets you deal with only the Git-tracked files (at least most of the time), then **git commit -a** will stage & commit all Git-tracked files in the repo at once, thereby reducing your commit for each repo down to a single, repeatable command-line command.